# Render "Digital Clock Style" Numbers

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Write the shortest program which will take a string of numbers (of up to *at least* 20 length) as input, and display the output using the standard digital clock style numbers.  For instance for input 81, a solution with ascii output would give:

```
 _
|_|  |
|_|  |
```

Graphical output is also acceptable, if it helps.

Comment: any upper limit on "take a string of numbers as input" ?

Comment: Hmm, let's say one row on an 80 column screen (20) is *good enough*.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407422/code-golf-seven-segments

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3324301/code-golf-digital-clock

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### APL (Dyalog) (45)

```
{3 3⍴' _|'[1+⍵⊤⍨9⍴3]}¨⎕UCS'ા8धगɯે૙ࣃଏ૽'[1+⍎¨⍞]
```

The string, `ા8धगɯે૙ࣃଏ૽`, are the unicode characters `2750 56 2343 2327 623 2759 2777 2243 2831 2813` (however, you should be able to just copy and paste it). They encode the numbers. The program reads a line from the keyboard.

Explanation:

- `1+⍎¨⍞`: read a line from the keyboard, parse each character as a digit, then add 1 to each number (APL arrays are 1-based by default).
- `⎕UCS'ા8धगɯે૙ࣃଏ૽'[`...`]`: Select the characters belonging to the digits of the numbers you entered, and look up the Unicode values.
- `{`...`}¨`: for each of these values, do:
- `1+⍵⊤⍨9⍴3`: get the first 9 base-3 digits from the value as expressed in base-3, and add 1  (because the arrays ar 1-based).
- `' _|'[`...`]`: select  a space, horizontal line, or vertical line depending on these digits
- `3 3⍴`: format as a 3-by-3 box.

Answer (score 44):

### [Funciton](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Funciton)

Not really a language suitable for golfing... but regardless, I tried to keep the code size as small as I could — quite a different challenge than in “usual” languages. This is **1555 characters** or **3110  bytes** (if encoded as UTF-16; UTF-8 is larger).

Here’s a screenshot of the program running. It really works:

[image: Here’s a screenshot of the program running. It really works :)]

Since this looks ugly in StackExchange due to the extra line spacing, consider running the following code in your browser’s JavaScript console to fix that: `$('pre').css('line-height',1)`

```
     ╓─╖ ╔╗┌─╖   ┌─╖
     ║ɧ║ ║╟┤↔╟┐ ┌┤‼╟┐
     ╙┬╜ ╚╝╘═╝│ │╘╤╝│
╔═╗  ┌┴────┐  │┌┴╖ ┌┴╖
║0║ ┌┴─┐  ┌┴─┐└┤ɧ╟─┤·╟┐
╚╤╝┌┴╖┌┴╖┌┴╖┌┴╖╘╤╝ ╘╤╝│
┌┘┌┤·╟┤ɦ╟┤·╟┤?╟ │  ┌┴╖│
│ │╘╤╝╘╤╝╘╤╝╘╤╝ └──┤‼╟┘
│┌┴╖│ ┌┴╖┌┘╔═╧╗    ╘═╝
└┤?╟┘┌┤?╟┘┌╢10║    ┌─────────┐
 ╘╤╝ │╘╤╝┌┘╚══╝ ┌─┬┘╔══╗┌──╖┌┴╖ ╓─╖
  ┘  └───┘╔════╗│┌┴┐║21╟┤>>╟┤·╟┐║ɦ║
╔════════╗║1005╟┘└┬┘╚══╝╘═╤╝╘╤╝│╙┬╜        ┌─┐
║14073768║╚════╝ ┌┴╖ ┌─╖ ┌┴╖┌┴╖└─┴─────────┘┌┴╖
║7584800 ╟───────┤?╟─┤‼╟─┤ɧ╟┤·╟─────────────┤·╟┐╔═══════╗╔══╗
╚════════╝       ╘╤╝ ╘╤╝ ╘╤╝╘╤╝    ╔══╗┌─╖┌┐╘╤╝│║2097151║║21╟┐
 ╔═══════════════╗│   ┘   │  │     ║48╟┤−╟┤├─┤┌┘╚══╤════╝╚══╝│
 ║140737555464224╟┘  ┌────┘┌┬┘     ╚══╝╘╤╝└┘┌┘│╓─╖ │┌┐┌─╖┌─╖┌┴─╖
 ╚═══════════════╝   │ ┌───┘└─────────┐┌┴─╖ │┌┘║↔║ ├┤├┤‼╟┤↔╟┤>>║
┌────────────┐┌────┐┌┴╖│┌────────────┐├┤<<║ ││ ╙┬╜┌┘└┘╘╤╝╘═╝╘╤═╝
│   ╔══╗╔═══╗├┘╓─╖ └┤·╟┘│   ╔══╗╔═══╗├┘╘╤═╝ │└─┐└─┤╔═╗┌┴╖ ┌──┘
│   ║95║║892║│┌╢‡╟┐ ╘╤╝ │   ║95║║877║│ ┌┘╔══╧═╗│  │║0╟┤?╟┬┘
│   ╚═╤╝╚═╤═╝││╙─╜│  │  │   ╚═╤╝╚═╤═╝│╔╧╗║2097║│  │╚═╝╘╤╝│
│╔══╗┌┴╖┌┐│  ││┌─╖│ ┌┴╖ │╔══╗┌┴╖┌┐│  │║1║║151 ║│  └──────┘
│║32╟┤?╟┤├┤  │└┤‼╟┘┌┤‡║ │║32╟┤?╟┤├┤  │╚═╝╚════╝│
│╚══╝╘╤╝└┘└──┴┐╘╤╝ │╘╤╝ │╚╤═╝╘╤╝└┘└──┴┐      ┌─┘
│    ┌┴╖     ┌┴╖┌─╖│ │ ┌┴╖│  ┌┴╖     ┌┴╖ ┌─╖┌┴╖
│    │‼╟─────┤·╟┤‼╟┘ │┌┤·╟┘  │‼╟─────┤·╟─┤‼╟┤‡║
└┐┌┐ ╘╤╝     ╘╤╝╘╤╝  ││╘╤╝┌┐ ╘╤╝     ╘╤╝ ╘╤╝╘╤╝
 ├┤├┐┌┴╖╔══╗  └──┐┌┐ │└┐├─┤├┐┌┴╖╔══╗  ├──┐└  │
 │└┘└┤?╟╢32║╔═══╗├┤│┌┴╖││ └┘└┤?╟╢32║╔═╧═╗│┌┐┌┴╖╔══╗
╔╧══╗╘╤╝╚══╝║881╟┘│├┤?╟┘│    ╘╤╝╚══╝║325║└┤├┤?╟╢32║
║927║╔╧══╗  ╚═══╝ └┘╘╤╝╔╧═══╗╔╧══╗  ╚═══╝ └┘╘╤╝╚══╝
╚═══╝║124╟───────────┘ ║1019║║124╟───────────┘
     ╚═══╝             ╚════╝╚═══╝
```

It could probably be smaller if I hadn’t made a mistake due to which the output was back to front; I fixed that by adding an extra function to reverse the input. Otherwise I would probably have to rewrite all of it.

I also made another mistake (swapping the operands in two calls to `‼`) which made it necessary to declare the extra `‡` function, but this one is so small it fits *inside* the main function and thus doesn’t add any characters!

Comment: Whoa, that looks cool. Not only the solution, the language too :-)

Comment: That is just awesome

Answer (score 9):

### J, <sup><strike>90</strike>, <strike>78</strike></sup> 68 chars

[ **update:** using unicode (1 byte) encoding:

```
,./(10 3 3$((90$3)#:256#.24x-~3&u:'%ė¨ÔW/~º»sy¡ăì<t÷²'){' _|'){~"./.Y
NB. utf characters are: 37 279 168 212 87 47 126 186 187 115 121 161 259 236 60 116 247 178
```

works as before: ]

```
,./(10 3 3$((90$3)#:1219424106940570763878862820444729939648410x){' _|'){~"./. '58321'
 _  _  _  _    
|_ |_| _| _|  |
 _||_| _||_   |
```

The key is in the encoding of digits as base-3 integers. Zero, for example is:

```
:
 _ 
| |
|_|
```

or `' _ | ||_|'`, which becomes 010202212<sub>3</sub> = 2750.

Comment: I could save 10 characters if J had high precision base-36 numbers. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: I'm using binary now. I wonder if trinary would save me some strokes?

Comment: congratulations for having the 1000th post on codegolf.SE! (`http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1000`)

Comment: 2+ years late but thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

#### wxpython, many characters

```
import wx, wx.gizmos as g

class T(wx.Frame):
 def __init__(_):
  wx.Frame.__init__(_, None, size = (800, 60))
  l = g.LEDNumberCtrl(_, -1)
  l.Value = raw_input()

class M(wx.App):
 def OnInit(_):
  T().Show()
  return 1

M().MainLoop()
```

Test

```
echo -n 81 | python codegolf-997-wx.py
```

[image]

ps: not a serious entry, but looks like graphical output is also acceptable, so I just gave it a try :-)

Comment: +1 Glad to see this :).

Comment: Way too many of you. :P

Answer (score 8):

### Golfscript - 66 chars

```
"placeholder text for userscript which counts chars             ";
```

`xxd`: (use `xxd -r` to revert)

```
0000000: 332c 7b3a 533b 2e7b 3438 2d22 5e70 285d  3,{:S;.{48-"^p(]
0000010: 7025 d3c4 4ab1 7d4a b8dc 4469 ce41 2222  p%..J.}J..Di.A""
0000020: f303 227b 6261 7365 7d2f 3330 2f53 3d33  .."{base}/30/S=3
0000030: 2f3d 7b22 5f20 7c22 3d7d 257d 256e 407d  /={"_ |"=}%}%n@}
0000040: 2f3b                                     /;
```

This follows most of the other answers in that there are no spaces between numbers and trailing spaces are kept in. A space between numbers can easily be added with `1+` before `{"_ |"=}%`. Packed into a base 3 number, and then as base 243 into a string.

Comment: Fair enough.  I updated the question to not bother with the unnecessary space between numbers.

Comment: I think the "placeholder..." thing is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <strike>205 209 198</strike> 179

```
i = IntegerDigits; t = Thread; r = Rule;
z@n_ := Row@i@n /. t[r[Range[0, 9], Grid[Partition[ReplacePart[Characters@" _ |_||_|", 
t[r[#, ""]]], 3], Spacings -> 0] & 
/@ (i /@ {5, 24578, 49, 47, 278, 67, 6, 4578, , 78})]]
```

**Usage**

```
z@1234567890
```

[image: digits]

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (145)

<s>148</s> 145

Since JavaScript doesn’t really have standard input/output, this is written as a function that takes a string and returns the output as a string.

```
function r(n){for(i=o="",b=" |_\n|",L=n.length;i<3*L;)o+=b[(c="ǪĠòƲĸƚǚĢǺƺ".charCodeAt(n[i%L])>>(i++/L|0)*3)&1]+b[c&2]+b[c&4]+b[i%L?0:3];return o}
```

Spaced out:

```
function r(n)
{
    for (i = o = "", b = " |_\n|", L = n.length;   i < 3*L;   )
        o += b [ (c = "ǪĠòƲĸƚǚĢǺƺ".charCodeAt(n[i%L]) >> (i++/L|0)*3) & 1 ] +
             b [ c&2 ] +
             b [ c&4 ] +
             b [ i%L ? 0 : 3 ];  // space or newline
    return o
}
```

Here’s how it works:

- Every digit shape is encoded in a Unicode character consisting of 9 bits.
- The first three bits are for the first row, etc.
- In each group of three bits, the first specifies whether the first character is `|` or space, the second whether it’s `_` or space, and the third again `|` or space.
- These three bits are retrieved as `c&1`, `c&2` and `c&4`, which are then used as indexes into the string `b`.
- At each iteration, `i%L` is the “x-coordinate”, i.e. the digit within the input `n`
- At each iteration, `i/L` is the “y-coordinate”, i.e. the row, but we need `|0` to make it an integer
- Finally, the spaces between the digits and the newlines between the lines are *also* retrieved by indexing into `b`, re-using the space character *and* the otherwise unused position 3 in that string! :)

Comment: Unicode! BAH! ... well, it *is* shorter than mine. +1

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 142

```
' _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ 
| |  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|
|_|  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _|'.lines{|l|puts x.chars.map{|i|l[i.to_i*3,3]}*''}
```

expects input in the variable `x`. examples:

```
x = '321'
#  _  _    
#  _| _|  |
#  _||_   |

x = '42'
#      _ 
#  |_| _|
#    ||_
```

Comment: ooooo. pretty! ...

Answer (score 5):

### python3.8.10 : <s>148</s> 138 bytes

Old (148):

```python
a=input()
N=0x375fa9176b3538d93ca41ea
for i in 0,3,6:print(''.join(' |'[N&x<<i>0]+' _'[N&x<<i+1>0]+' |'[N&x<<i+2>0]for x in[1<<9*int(x)for x in a]))
```

New (138):

```python
a=input()
N=0x375fa9176b3538d93ca41ea
for i in -1,2,5:print(''.join(' |_|'[(N&x<<i+k>0)*k]for x in[1<<9*int(x)for x in a]for k in(1,2,3)))
```

[try the code here](https://tio.run/##NYzRCoIwGIXvfYpdtc0snL9zLmaP4AtIxLKkNdhEDBb47kuD7g7nfN8ZP/PTO4hRN8aN75nQpG3yAIIPWjJR3YBDfZfQ65I9dDL4CRlkHDqwrMj4aZyMmwnGx5c3jmC0XBfckXYXlDJ7e85pai@bE1anY0rJdOMD/XdI/2a7RrI9AqU0RlZAyStRy/wL)

Comment: Welcome to code golf! Your answer is golfed, nice btw, but you require a tio.run link to go with your answer to prove it works thx! Link: https://tio.run/#python3

Comment: @DialFrost a TIO link is nice to have, so people can easily test it, but not at all required.

Comment: [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##FczRCsIgFIDh@57Cq9S2Yu7MOWM9SUScWiMTVIaBwd7d5t1/83/hF9/eQc54MS58I@O72S/EEOOOom5reQ6LcZFRevp44xgl632l1yaBkjNqofoHSBgmDU/sxAv3YhxNZSt9KFfi6CZib4VMG0mQlLRbsqID5zxn0UInezXo5g8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - 97 chars

```
:*{32' _':$@'14'{?~!=}:&~32}%n*{:x' |':|\'1237'&$x'017'&|x'56'&}%n*{:x|\'134579'&$x'147'&|x'2'&}%
```

Comment: Use the backtick to save a char for all the numeric strings (how do I insert this character in the code format?)

Comment: @Nabb: You can’t — StackExchange is crap like that...

Answer (score 3):

## D: 295 Characters

```
import std.stdio;void main(string[]a){string[3]o;foreach(c;a[1]){int n=cast(int)(c)-48;auto e=" ";o[0]~=n!=1&&n!=4?" _ ":"   ";o[1]~=!n||n>3&&n!=7?"|":e;o[1]~=n>1&&n!=7?"_":e;o[1]~=n<5||n>6?"|":e;o[2]~=!(n&1)&&n!=4?"|":e;o[2]~=!n||n>1&&n!=4&&n!=7?"_":e;o[2]~=n!=2?"|":e;}foreach(l;o)writeln(l);}
```

More Legibly:

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] a)
{
    string[3] o;

    foreach(c; a[1])
    {
        int n = cast(int)(c) - 48;
        auto e = " ";

        o[0] ~= n != 1 && n != 4 ? " _ " : "   ";

        o[1] ~= !n || n > 3 && n != 7 ? "|" : e;
        o[1] ~= n > 1 && n != 7 ? "_" : e;
        o[1] ~= n < 5 || n > 6 ? "|" : e;

        o[2] ~= !(n&1) && n != 4 ? "|" : e;
        o[2] ~= !n || n > 1 && n != 4 && n != 7 ? "_" : e;
        o[2] ~= n != 2 ? "|" : e;
    }

    foreach(l; o)
        writeln(l);
}
```

Comment: Wow, first D answer I've ever seen on this site!

Answer (score 3):

#### Windows PowerShell, 127

```
$i="$input"[0..99]
'☺ ☺☺ ☺☺☺☺☺','♠☻♥♥♦♣♣☻♦♦','♦☻♣♥☻♥♦☻♦♥'|%{$c=$_
""+($i|%{('···0·_·0··|0·_|0|_|0|_·0|·|'-split0)[$c[$_-48]]})}
```

Since the strings contain some unpleasant-to-write characters, a hexdump for your convenience:

```
000: 24 69 3D 22 24 69 6E 70 │ 75 74 22 5B 30 2E 2E 39  $i="$input"[0..9
010: 39 5D 0A 27 01 00 01 01 │ 00 01 01 01 01 01 27 2C  9]◙'☺ ☺☺ ☺☺☺☺☺',
020: 27 06 02 03 03 04 05 05 │ 02 04 04 27 2C 27 04 02  '♠☻♥♥♦♣♣☻♦♦','♦☻
030: 05 03 02 03 04 02 04 03 │ 27 7C 25 7B 24 63 3D 24  ♣♥☻♥♦☻♦♥'|%{$c=$
040: 5F 0A 22 22 2B 28 24 69 │ 7C 25 7B 28 27 20 20 20  _◙""+($i|%{('
050: 30 20 5F 20 30 20 20 7C │ 30 20 5F 7C 30 7C 5F 7C  0 _ 0  |0 _|0|_|
060: 30 7C 5F 20 30 7C 20 7C │ 27 2D 73 70 6C 69 74 30  0|_ 0| |'-split0
070: 29 5B 24 63 5B 24 5F 2D │ 34 38 5D 5D 7D 29 7D     )[$c[$_-48]]})}
```

Comment: Look at all the smileys..

Answer (score 3):

**Java Solution: <s>585</s> 570 Chars**

I don't think I'll be attempting any more golfing in Java...

```
import java.util.*;
public class CG997{public static void main(String[]args){
short[][]lets=new short[][]{{0,1,3,2,0,4,2,1,4},{0,0,3,0,0,4,0,0,4},{0,1,3,0,1,
4,2,1,3},{0,1,3,0,1,4,0,1,4},{0,0,3,2,1,4,0,0,4},{0,1,3,2,1,3,0,1,4},{0,1,3,2,1
,3,2,1,4},{0,1,3,0,0,4,0,0,4},{0,1,3,2,1,4,2,1,4},{0,1,3,2,1,4,0,0,4}};
String[]syms=new String[]{" ","_","|","  ","| "};
String s=new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
for(int o=0;o<3;o++){for(char c:s.toCharArray()){for(int i =0;i<3;i++)
System.out.print(syms[lets[Short.parseShort(c+"")][i+o*3]]);
}System.out.println();}}}
```

Comment: Your java version is way better/shorter than mine :)    btw!...  does 6 in digital clock representation has a cap (_) at top or not? I got confused after you output!

Comment: Upon checking the coffee maker behind me, the 6's should have a cap.  I'll update my solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 11 characters

```
toilet "$i"
```

Yes I know, I'm cheating.

You need to have toilet installed.

Comment: And have the default font set to one with 7 segment display numbers. `figlet` would also work.

Answer (score 3):

## gForth, <s>186</s> 175 chars

New version:

```
: s query parse-word bounds s" D@DD@DDDDDb`ddfFF`fff`Fd`df`f`" bounds do cr 2dup do i c@ '0 - j + c@ 3 0 do dup 3 and s"  _|" drop + 1 type 4 / loop drop loop 10 +loop bye ; s
```

This actually bothers to exit (+3 chars) as well :). Here is the more readable version, it does some bit-packing to reduce the LUT size by 1/3, but the resulting code is more complex so it's not much of a savings:

```
: 7s query parse-word bounds 
    s" D@DD@DDDDDb`ddfFF`fff`Fd`df`f`"
    bounds do 
        cr
        2dup do
            i c@ '0 - j + c@
            3 0 do
                dup 3 and
                s"  _|" drop + 1 type
                4 / \ shorter than an rshift
            loop
            drop
        loop
    10 +loop bye ;
7s
```

Old version:

```
: s query parse-word bounds s"  _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ | |  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_||_|  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_|  |" bounds do cr 2dup do i c@ '0 - 3 * j + 3 type loop 30 +loop ; s
```

This leaves the stack unbalanced and doesn't bother to exit the interpreter. Here is a cleaner more readable version

```
: 7s query parse-word bounds 
    s"  _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ | |  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_||_|  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_|  |"
    bounds do 
        cr
        2dup do
            i c@ '0 - 3 * j + 3 type
        loop
    30 +loop 2drop bye ;
7s
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>280</s> 274 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){String x="",y=x,z=x;for(int c:a[0].getBytes()){c-=48;x+=" "+(c==4|c==1?" ":"_")+" ";y+=(c==7|c>0&c<4?" ":"|")+(c==7|c<2?" ":"_")+(c>4&c<7?" ":"|");z+=(c%2<1&c!=4?"|":" ")+(c%3==1?" ":"_")+(c==2?" ":"|");}System.out.print(x+"\n"+y+"\n"+z);}}
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##RY9Bb8IwDIX/ShYJlCpQtSVbGa2ZtPtOHAGhKAQUJlLUZihpy2/PAp3Yxbbee58tn/iVT6uL1Kf9t/dKG1kfuJDoq2sMN0qga6X26MyVJitTK31cb3nUDSOygPHEgZ20YItDVZPAI7Hg62QbH6X5dEY2JIo6MQU2LywFAcD6UNIPjBDCC4x2CBeOAgli3otlMhYlC2awehzRP7nMBmn3kJYshPJnqGjv@Cgr07F4gQD3972P5Gg2nHqiANk/d1u5xshzXP2Y@BL@McRSvNGYuqG1IXLz3qfZjL2@5fP35Bc)

```java
interface M{                     // Class
  static void main(String[]a){   //  Mandatory main-method
    String x="",                 //   String for row 1, starting empty
           y=x,                  //   String for row 2, starting empty
           z=x;                  //   String for row 3, starting empty
    for(int c:a[0].getBytes()){  //   Loop over the bytes of the input
      c-=48;                     //    Convert the byte to integer
      x+=                        //    Append to row 1:
         c==4|c==1?              //     If the digit is a 1 or 4:
            "   "                //       Append three spaces
           :                     //      Else:
            " _ ";               //       Append a space + underscore + space instead
      y+=                        //    Append to row 2:
         (c==7|c>0&c<4?          //      If the digit is 1, 2, 3, or 7:
           " "                   //       Append a space
          :                      //      Else:
           "|")                  //       Append a pipe
         +(c==7|c<2?             //     +If the digit is 0, 1, or 7:
            " "                  //       Append a space
           :                     //      Else:
            "_")                 //       Append an underscore
         +(c>4&c<7?              //     +If the digit is 5 or 6:
            " "                  //       Append a space
           :                     //      Else:
            "|");                //       Append a pipe
      z+=                        //    Append to row 3:
         (c%2<1&c!=4?            //      If the digit is 0, 2, 6 or 8:
           "|"                   //       Append a pipe
          :                      //      Else:
           " ")                  //       Append a space
          +(c%3==1?              //     +If the digit is 1, 4, or 7:
             " "                 //       Append a space
            :                    //      Else:
             "_")                //       Append a pipe
          +(c==2?                //     +If the digit is 2:
             " "                 //       Append a space
            :                    //      Else:
             "|");               //       Append a pipe
    }                            //   End of loop
    System.out.print(x+"\n"+y+"\n"+z);
                                 //   Print the three rows
  }                              //  End of main-method
}                                // End of class
```

As function this would be [**212 bytes**](https://tio.run/##RVBdb4IwFH33V9w10ZQgRJENZ6nLsuf5ssdtMV3FDafFtNWAwm/HixB9uU3Px705ZyOOwsv2idqs/mu5FcbAu0jVuQeQKpvotZAJLJovwIfVqfoFSeWf0J/fYByGeNXDYaywqYQFKOBQG29@7sQ5J2RY8Hx44jlbZ5riVpAz45ylx8Mpy10uOQ9LHOMXgkfIjMASCCtcThGMSjkfDWQcIolUSRy3g@OghZZXaB6iKLqJ2Kmx94N4PJAPHM1ls/eq7E/aUzcr58HdV@nEHrSC3CVfirhF@5xYVbMm5/7ws8WcXdxjlq5gh3XRNi12Ipyuq8LYZOdnB@vvkbJU@ZKScTAJH5@i6fOI@DZ7wxpftRYFdZyuyqqu75oL) instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>118</s> 115 bytes

-3 bytes: realised a cheaper way to loop through `|_|`

```javascript
n=>[613550340,2132540234,1866373582].map(d=>n.replace(/./g,c=>(i=1<<c*3,g=s=>d&(i*=2)?s:' ')`|`+g`_`+g`|`)).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7PDoIgAIDxu0/RKaARCghSiT1Ia8nwz3AGTpsn353qWNffd/kGs5rFzm56HVcVOx29rm6SciEynmeYUc5EnjGeY6qk5AUXit3J00yw0ZUnczuNxrYwJWmPra7A9tjAry66avbQHTRD1@UMdgA7TcvSHjhCiAzB@Tqpow1@CWNLxtDDDgJFAUKX5E8z@hkRslCnb41v)

Takes input as a string of digits, uses three magic numbers which represent the state of each segment for each digit; every three bits is a digit.

Ungolfed and explained

```javascript
n => [ // magic numbers
              //      9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
  613550340,  // = 0b010_010_010_010_010_000_010_010_000_010_0
  2132540234, // = 0b111_111_100_011_011_111_110_110_100_101_0
  1866373582  // = 0b110_111_100_111_110_100_110_011_100_111_0
].map(d => n.replace(/./g,
  c => (
    i = 1 << c * 3, // initialise i to first bit of digit
    g = s => d & (i *= 2) ? s : ' ' // function to check bits
  )`|` + g`_` + g`|` // do function on each of '|_|'
)).join`
```

Comment: [111](https://tio.run/##XY7LEoIgAADvfkWngCQEEaQS@pCmCQYfo2PoaOPJf7e8dtnD7mU7t7jZT@34OS9qq/UWtHlIxoWgPKM4ZTwVGU15hpmSkudcqPRJ3m6EpTaBTNXYO1/BhCQN9tpAf9IcN3rWpjyyoohjf5@v4ACQXW3c2NeO1SJEuqENNrKbH8I89BXphwbWECgGELpFf5ay34GQubrsdfsC)

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 2,095

```
public class DigitalNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char[][] panel = new char[3][120]; //A 20 digit panel!
        int digXIndex = 0;int digYIndex = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<args[0].length(); i++){
            int dig=Integer.parseInt(""+args[0].charAt(i));
            panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;   
            digYIndex++;
            if (dig!=1 && dig!=4)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='_';  
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;
            digYIndex++;
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32; 
            digYIndex=3*i;
            digXIndex++;
            if (dig!=1 && dig!=2 && dig!=3 && dig!=7)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='|';    
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;
            digYIndex++;
            if (dig!=1 && dig!=0 && dig!=7)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='_';    
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;
            digYIndex++;
            if (dig!=6 && dig!=5)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='|';  
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;
            digYIndex=3*i;
            digXIndex++;
            if (dig!=6 && dig!=8 && dig!=2 && dig!=0)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;  
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='|';
            digYIndex++;
            if (dig!=7 && dig!=4 && dig!=1)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='_';  
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;
            digYIndex++;
            if (dig!=2)
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]='|';  
            else
                panel[digXIndex][digYIndex]=32;
            digXIndex=0;
            digYIndex+=(i*3)+1;
        }       
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<120; j++)
                if (panel[i][j]!=0)
                System.out.print((char)(panel[i][j]));
                else
                    System.out.print("");
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

SAMPLE I/O

```
java DigitalNumber 98765432109876543210
     _  _  _  _  _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _  _     _  _     _ 
    |_||_|  ||_ |_ |_| _| _|  || ||_||_|  ||_ |_ |_| _| _|  || |
     _||_|  ||_| _|  | _||_   ||_| _||_|  ||_| _|  | _||_   ||_|
```

Comment: I should start hating java :)

Comment: Java is great for many things, but terse code is *not* one of them.

Comment: Well, this code isn't even golfed. It could be way shorter.

Comment: I golfed your code a bit ;)

Answer (score 2):

### C# 369 Characters

```
static void Main(string[] a){var b = new[] {123,72,61,109,78,103,119,73,127,111};var g = new[]{" _  ","|","_","| ","|","_","| "};a[0].ToCharArray().SelectMany((x,w)=>g.Select((y,i)=>new{s=((b[x-48]>>i&1)==1)?y:new String(' ',y.Length),j=i,v=w})).GroupBy(z=>(z.j+2)/3).ToList().ForEach(q=>Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", q.OrderBy(l=>l.v).Select(k=>k.s).ToArray())));}
```

I could easily cut *a few* characters out.  The point was more to abuse LINQ :)

More whitespace version:

```
static void Main(string[] a)
{
    var b = new[] {123, 72, 61, 109, 78, 103, 119, 73, 127, 111};
    var g = new[] { " _  ", "|", "_", "| ", "|", "_", "| " };
    a[0].ToCharArray().SelectMany(
        (x,w)=>g.Select(
           (y,i)=>new{s=((b[x-48]>>i&1)==1)?y:new String(' ',y.Length),j=i,v=w}))
            .GroupBy(z=>(z.j+2)/3).ToList().ForEach(
            q=>Console.WriteLine(
                String.Join("", q.OrderBy(l=>l.v).Select(k=>k.s).ToArray())));
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need a class declaration and `using`s (409). Then there is a some unnecessary whitespace that can be removed (402). The task states that whitespace between the digits shall be omitted (399).

Comment: Uh, thanks.  I edited the task because nobody was following the original whitespace rule.  Feel free to edit the answer if it offends you, because I just don't care.

Comment: `g` is used only once, so you can save 7 characters by inlining it.

Comment: Actually `b` is also used only once, so you can inline it too. Also, you can save a *lot* of characters if you change the integer array to `"{H=mNgwI\x7fo"`, or even shorter if you change `\x7f` to the actual character #127 (which is unprintable, but permissible). The `>>` will still work because there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`.

Comment: Also, the `.ToCharArray()` and the `.ToArray()` are both redundant, you can just remove them :)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <del>218</del> <del>180</del> 176

`b=map(int,raw_input());a=map(int,bin(914290166014670372457936330)[2:]);c=' |_';p=lambda k:''.join(c[a[9*n+k]]+c[2*a[9*n+1+k]]+c[a[9*n+2+k]]for n in b)+'\n';print p(6)+p(0)+p(3)`

With line breaks:

```
b=map(int,raw_input())
a=map(int,bin(914290166014670372457936330)[2:])
p=lambda k:''.join(' |'[a[9*n+k]]+' _'[a[9*n+1+k]]+' |'[a[9*n+2+k]]for n in b)+'\n'
print p(6)+p(0)+p(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>140</s> <s>136</s> <s>133</s> <s>131</s> <s>129</s> 128 bytes

<sup>I could save <s>5</s> 7 more with extended ascii: one each for `"| _"` and the linebreak, three for `~"z/]{4lno~|"` (bitwise negation would turn everything to extended ascii characters = no special characters, and PHP doesn´t need quotes there), two for `-1` (it´s only there to keep the map in standard ascii). But for readability and compatibility, I stay with standard ascii.</sup>

```php
for(;""<$c=$argv[1][$i++];)for($n=753754680;$n>>=3;)$r[$p++%3].="| _"[ord(~"z/]{4lno~|"[$c])-1>>$n%8&1?:$n&2];echo join("
",$r);
```

**the bitmap**

- Take LEDS `_`,`|_|`, `|_|` as bits `-6-`,`024`,`135` (bit number &2 is 0 for vertical LEDs)
- Create bitmaps for numbers 0..9: `[123,48,94,124,53,109,111,112,127,125]`
- Decrease by 1 to make them all printable ascii codes -> `"z/]{4lno~|"`
- negate -> `~"z/]{4lno~|"` (allows ternary shorthand in character selection)

**the template**

- use `7` for the spaces -> `767`,`024`,`135`
- regroup by columns instead of rows -> `701`,`623`,`745` (renders `$p=0` obsolete)
- reverse -> `547326107` (read the map from right to left; allows arithmetic looping)
- append zero -> `5473261070` (allows to combine shift with test in loop head)
- read octal, convert to decimal -> `753754680` (two bytes shorter: one digit and the prefix)

**breakdown**

```php
for(;""<$c=$argv[1][$i++];) // loop through input characters
    for($n=753754680;$n>>=3;)   // loop through template
        $r[$p++%3].="| _"[          // append character to row $p%3:
            ord(~"z/]{4lno~|"[$c])-1// decode bitmap
                >>$n%8&1            // test bit $n%8 (always 1 for bit 7)
            ?                       // if set: 1 (space)
            :$n&2                   // else: 2 (underscore) for bits 2,3,6; 0 (pipe) else
        ];
echo join("\n",$r);         // print result
```

Comment: +16 bytes for hexadecimal: `ord(~"z/]{4lno~|v.J=NF"[hexdec($c)])-1`

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 114 bytes

```powershell
param($a)6,3,0|%{$l=$_
-join($a|% t*y|%{('   0 _ 0 _|0|_ 0| |0  |0|_|'-split0)[(+('f-SR5Z^mvr'["$_"])-shr$l)%8]})}
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($a)6,3,0|%{$l=$_
-join($a|% t*y|%{('   0 _ 0 _|0|_ 0| |0  |0|_|'-split0)[(+('f-SR5Z^mvr'["$_"])-shr$l)%8]})}

}

&$f "1234567890"
&$f "81"
```

Output:

```powershell
    _  _     _  _  _  _  _  _
  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|| |
  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _||_|
 _
|_|  |
|_|  |
```

Main idea:

Each standard digital clock style number contains 3 lines. Moreover, the first line contains only 2 options. A total of 6 options. Therefore, 7 bits are enough to encode each digit.

```powershell
line str=@('   ', ' _ ', ' _|', '|_ ', '| |', '  |', '|_|')

#    line str    binary       dec    ASCII
-    --------    ---------    ---    -----
0 -> 1 
     4 
     6        -> 1 100 110 -> 102 -> 'f'

1 -> 0
     5
     5        -> 0 101 101 ->  45 -> '-'

...

8 -> 1
     6
     6        -> 1 110 110 -> 118 -> 'v'

9 -> 1
     6
     2        -> 1 110 010 -> 114 -> 'r'
```

So, the string `f-SR5Z^mvr` encodes all segments for all standard digital clock style numbers.

Note: The order of the `line str` was specially selected so that all codes were in the interval `32..126`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `jṠ`, 40 bytes

```
»*ż↵↲ṡŀ≬₍ṡfl₆ǎ8≠∇ƈH»`_ |`τ3/₀/ƛ£⁰ƛ¥nIi;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j%E1%B9%A0&code=%C2%BB*%C5%BC%E2%86%B5%E2%86%B2%E1%B9%A1%C5%80%E2%89%AC%E2%82%8D%E1%B9%A1fl%E2%82%86%C7%8E8%E2%89%A0%E2%88%87%C6%88H%C2%BB%60_%20%7C%60%CF%843%2F%E2%82%80%2F%C6%9B%C2%A3%E2%81%B0%C6%9B%C2%A5nIi%3B%E1%B9%85&inputs=0123456789&header=&footer=)

A mess. Uses base-3 compression.

```
»...»                     # Compressed integer containing all digits
     `_ |`τ               # Decompress by custom base-3
           3/             # Divide into 3
             ₀/           # Divide each piece into 10
               ƛ          # Map this new list to...
                £         # Store to register
                 ⁰ƛ    ;  # Map this new input to...
                   ¥      # Push register
                    nIi   # Get correct value
                        ṅ # Join
                          # (Implicit) Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ocaml, 268

```
let t=function|'1'|'4'->"   "|_->" _ "let m=function|'0'->"| |"|'1'|'7'->"  |"|'2'|'3'->" _|"|_->"|_|"|'5'|'6'->"|_ "let b=function|'0'|'8'->"|_|"|'1'|'4'|'7'->"  |"|'2'->"|_ "|_->" _|"let f s=let g h=String.iter(fun c->print_string(h c))s;print_newline()ing t;g m;g b
```

Readable version

```
let t = function
  | '1'
  | '4' -> "   "
  | _ -> " _ "
let m = function
  | '0' -> "| |"
  | '1'
  | '7' -> "  |"
  | '2'
  | '3' -> " _|"
  | _ -> "|_|"
  | '5'
  | '6' -> "|_ "
let b = function
  | '0'
  | '8' -> "|_|"
  | '1'
  | '4'
  | '7' -> "  |"
  | '2' -> "|_ "
  | _ -> " _|"
let f s =
  let g h =
    String.iter (fun c -> print_string (h c)) s;
    print_newline () in
  g t;
  g m;
  g b
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ghostscript <del>(270)</del> <del>(248)</del> (214)

*Edit:* More substitutions. Removed space between digits.

*Edit:* Even more substitutions. Main loop now looks like what it does!

```
/F{forall}def[48<~HUp;::1ncBInp~>{1 index 1 add}F
pop/*{dup
2 idiv exch
2 mod
1 eq}/P{print}/#{( )P}/?{ifelse
P}/O{{( )}?}/|{*{(|)}O}/_{*{(_)}O}>>begin[[[[ARGUMENTS{{load
# _ #}F()=]2{{| _ |}F()=]}repeat]pop[[[[}F
```

Uses ghostscript's argument-processing feature: invoke with `gs -dNODISPLAY -- digit.ps 012 345 6789`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Delphi || 453 (568 With format)

Not even close enough to win but it was fun to do ^.^

```
const asc: array[0..9] of array[0..2] of string = ((' _ ','| |','|_|'),('   ','  |','  |'),(' _ ',' _|','|_ '),(' _ ',' _|',' _|'),('   ','|_|','  |'),(' _ ','|_ ',' _|'),(' _ ','|_ ','|_|'),(' _ ','  |','  |'),(' _ ','|_|','|_|'),(' _ ','|_|',' _|'));var s,l:string;x,i:integer;begin Readln(s);s:=StringReplace(s,' ','',[rfReplaceAll]);for I := 0 to 2 do begin l:='';for x := 1 to length(s) do l := l + asc[StrToInt(s[x])][i];writeln(l);end;readln;end.
```

#### With format

```
const
asc: array[0..9] of array[0..2] of string = (
  (' _ ','| |','|_|'),
  ('   ','  |','  |'),
  (' _ ',' _|','|_ '),
  (' _ ',' _|',' _|'),
  ('   ','|_|','  |'),
  (' _ ','|_ ',' _|'),
  (' _ ','|_ ','|_|'),
  (' _ ','  |','  |'),
  (' _ ','|_|','|_|'),
  (' _ ','|_|',' _|'));
var
s,l:string;
x,i:integer;
begin
    Readln(s);
    s:=StringReplace(s,' ','',[rfReplaceAll]);
    for I := 0 to 2 do
    begin
      l:='';
      for x := 1 to length(s) do
        l := l + asc[StrToInt(s[x])][i];
      writeln(l);
    end;
    readln
```

end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-F`, 96 bytes

```perl
map{@m=/./g;say map{substr'    _  _||_ | |  ||_|',3*$m[$_],3}@F}1011011111,4522633566,6532526562
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYdBCsIwEEWvkkWhIGmbzHRGRYSuuvMEIqGCiGBsaOpCTK/umL7/Fu@H2/QkET@Eb@ePTd3cD3H4qPXH9zXOU6kyLpuSUylP5Uilxk3hz4W7aFy6frHGrmZ0SwCMSMyaCYGAiUHEWMCWeLvb/8YwP8ZXlOpEtbFGqv4P)

The string     `_  _||_ | |  ||_|` represents the possible "cross sections" of the digits (grabbed the idea from @mazzy's PowerShell solution).  The numbers in the list `1011011111,4522633566,6532526562` represent indices into that string for the first, second, and third line of each of the digits 0-9.  The index must be multiplied by 3 to get to the correct position.  This loops over each character input (stored in the `@F` array by the `-F` option on the command line), finds the correct index into the string for that input, and then outputs the result.

#### Old version: [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 102 bytes

```perl
for$b(' a ',dbe,fcg){say s%.%'$b=~y/'.(b,abcdf,dg,df,acf,ef,e,bcdf,Z,f)[$&]."/ /r=~y/a-z/___|/r"%geer}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glSUNdIVFBXSclKVUnLTlds7o4sVKhWFVPVV0lybauUl9dTyNJJzEpOSVNJyVdB0gmJqfppAKRDlgsSidNM1pFLVZPSV9BvwikIVG3Sj8@Pr5Gv0hJNT01taj2/39DI2MTUzNzC0sDBOtffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7p5AA)

Considers the characters of the display to be named like this:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
 & a &   \\ \hline
d &b & e \\ \hline
f & c & g \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The code iterates over strings representing each line of that table `(' a ',dbe,fcg)`.  On each of those, it changes the elements turned off into spaces. This information is in the list
`(b,abcdf,dg,df,acf,ef,e,bcdf,z,f)`.  It uses the current element of the input (stored in `$_` by the commandline switch and extracted by the pattern match into `$&`) to index into that list.  Finally, the letters a, b, and c are changed to underscores (`_`) and all other letters into pipes (`|`).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•ʒïgÈ¨&Û≠∍›vâsŸ”_‡y•…| _ÅвJ3ôTäÅвø»
```

Outputs with additional single space between the output-digits. If this is not allowed, it'll be 1 byte longer by adding a `J` before the `»`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9vc2FiaWX//@KAosqSw69nw4jCqCbDm@KJoOKIjeKAunbDonPFuOKAnV/igKF54oCi4oCmfCBfw4XQskozw7RUw6RJU8Oow7jCu///MTM1NzkyNDY4MA)

**Explanation:**

```python
•ʒïgÈ¨&Û≠∍›vâsŸ”_‡y•
          # Push compressed integer 5210925748351095970666976465591163407510385
 …| _     # Push string "| _"
     Åв   # Convert the integer to this custom base (basically convert it to
          # base-length - 3 in this case - and index each into the string)
       J  # Join this list of characters to a single string:
          #  " _ | ||_|     |  | _  _||_  _  _| _|   |_|  | _ |_  _| _ |_ |_| _   |  | _ |_||_| _ |_| _|"
3ô        # Split it into triplets
  Tä      # Split that into 10 equal-sized parts
    Åв    # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to this custom base
      ø   # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       »  # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•ʒïgÈ¨&Û≠∍›vâsŸ”_‡y•` is `5210925748351095970666976465591163407510385`.
[See this 05AB1E tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120966/52210) to understand how the ASCII-art string `" _ | ||_|     |  | _  _||_  _  _| _|   |_|  | _ |_  _| _ |_ |_| _   |  | _ |_||_| _ |_| _|"` is compressed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `lcd`, 3 bytes

```
lcd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQk5yikJmvYM3FpWRoZKH0H8j/X16UWZL6HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 33 bytes

```
»@Ǐ+Ẇ₃e⋏UWṡ:≠7ẏŀz→=»`| _`τ₀/3/τ∩⁋
```

Ports the 05AB1E answer.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu0DHjyvhuobigoNl4ouPVVfhuaE64omgN+G6j8WAeuKGkj3Cu2B8IF9gz4TigoAvMy/PhOKIqeKBiyIsIiIsIjEzNTc5MjQ2ODAiXQ==)

### How?

```
»@Ǐ+Ẇ₃e⋏UWṡ:≠7ẏŀz→=»`| _`τ₀/3/τ∩⁋
»@Ǐ+Ẇ₃e⋏UWṡ:≠7ẏŀz→=»              # Push compressed integer 5210925748351095970666976465591163407510385
                    `| _`         # Push string "| _"
                         τ        # Convert the integer to this custom base
                          ₀/      # Split into ten pieces
                            3/    # Split each into three pieces
                              τ   # For each string, convert the (implicit) input to this custom base
                               ∩  # Transpose
                                ⁋ # Join on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl (<del>182</del> 180)

```
#!perl -l
$_=<<7;
 _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ 
| |  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|
|_|  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _|
7
@b=map{[/(...)/g]}split/\n/;@d=split//,<>;for$p(@b){print map$p->[$_],@d}
```

reads from STDIN.

```
$ perl 7segment.pl 
1234567890987654321
    _  _     _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _     _  _     _ 
  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|| ||_||_|  ||_ |_ |_| _| _|  || |
  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _||_| _||_|  ||_| _|  | _||_   ||_|
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Python, 227 chars**

```
a="   ";b=" _ ";c="|_|";d="| |";e="|  ";f="  |";g="|_ ";h=" _|"
z=[[b,d,c],[a,f,f],[b,h,g],[b,h,h],[a,c,f],[b,g,h],[b,g,c],[b,f,f],[b,c,c],[b,c,h]]
x=map(int,raw_input())
for i in range(3):
 for j in x:
  print z[j][i],
 print
```

Simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.4.3 - <del>1514</del> 858 bytes

The temptation to solve this was too great not to sign up and answer =P

I'm a bit new to Python, so I formatted my program nice and neat (or at least I did). Improvements are greatly appreciated!

```
import sys;l1,l2,l3,l4,l5="";num=input()
for c in num:
    if c=="1":
        l1+=" oo  ";l2+="  o  ";l3+="  o  ";l4+="  o  ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="2":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="   o ";l3+="oooo ";l4+="o    ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="3":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="   o ";l3+=" ooo ";l4+="   o ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="4":
        l1+="o  o ";l2+="o  o ";l3+="oooo ";l4+="   o ";l5+="   o "
    if c=="5":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="o    ";l3+="oooo ";l4+="   o ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="6":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="o    ";l3+="oooo ";l4+="o  o ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="7":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="   o ";l3+="   o ";l4+="   o ";l5+="   o "
    if c=="8":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="o  o ";l3+="oooo ";l4+="o  o ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="9":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="o  o ";l3+="oooo ";l4+="   o ";l5+="oooo "
    if c=="0":
        l1+="oooo ";l2+="o  o ";l3+="o  o ";l4+="o  o ";l5+="oooo "
print(l1+"\n"+l2+"\n"+l3+"\n"+l4+"\n"+l5)
```

Edit: Shortened variable names, used ; to shorten, only one space at end of output numbers, defined variables all at once.

New lines are 2 bytes (CRLF) and I used tabs instead of 4 spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Since this is a code golf challenge, you'll want to make your code as short as possible. [These tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) maybe be helpful for golfing.

Comment: _"I used tabs instead of 4 spaces"_ I'm confused. Why weren't you using tabs anyway? ;)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 216 bytes

```
?INPUT N$DIM A[14]COPY A,@A@A
DATA 1,0,0,1,3,1,1,3,0,4,3,4,1,6FOR D=0 TO LEN(N$)-1X=ASC("w$]m.k{%\o"[VAL(N$[D])])FOR I=0TO 6T=I*2IF X<<31THEN GBOX A[T]+D*5,A[T+1],A[T]+D*5+!(I MOD 3),A[T+1]+!!(I MOD 3)
X=X/2NEXT
NEXT
```

Using graphics instead of text, because it's probably shorter.

Explanation:

```
PRINT 'so the input and output don't overlap
INPUT NUMBER$ 'get number
DIM PTS[7*2] 'locations of segments
COPY PTS,@PTDATA 'copy data into array
@PTDATA
DATA 1,0,0,1,3,1,1,3,0,4,3,4,1,6 'stored as x,y,x,y,...
FOR DIGIT=0 TO LEN(NUMBER$)-1
 NUM=ASC("w$]m.k{%\o"[VAL(NUMBER$[DIGIT])]) 'get digit data. That data string doesn't have any non-ASCII characters, except \ which is 127 in SB.
 FOR I=0 TO 7-1 'draw each segment
  T=I*2 'position of point in array
  IF X AND 1 THEN GLINE PTS[T]+DIGIT*5,PTS[T+1],PTS[T]+DIGIT*5+!(I MOD 3),PTS[T+1]+!!(I MOD 3) 'draw segment. I MOD 3 determines whether it's horizontal or vertical.
  X=X>>1 'shift to next bit
 NEXT
NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, <s>230</s> <s>229</s> <s>225</s> <s>223</s> <s>218</s> <s>207</s> <s>204</s> 198 bytes

```cpp
#import<iostream>
#define d for(auto
std::string v[3],t,g="|_| =2$0^262\'032;2$2?272";main(){std::cin>>t;d i:t)d j:{0,1,2})d k:{0,1,2})v[k]+=g[g[i*2-92+!k]>>j+k/2*3&1?j:3];d j:v)std::cout<<j<<'\n';}
```

Reads from stdin and output to stdout.

**Explanation:**

```cpp
#import<iostream>                // string inside

std::string v[3], t, g="|_| "    // symbol on different horizontal position
      "=2$0^262\'032;2$2?272";   // space(0) or not(1) for each number and position
                                 // binary representation, last 6 bits is used
                                 // even positions are for row 1, 2; odds are for row 0

main() {
    std::cin>>t;                 // input
    for (auto i:t)               // for each character
        for (auto j:{0,1,2})     // for each horizontal position
            for (auto k:{0,1,2}) // for each vertical position
                v[k]+=g[         // use first four chars only
                    g[i*2-92     // i*2-96 is number*2, +4 to skip first four
                        +!k]     // row 0 uses another character
                    >>j+k/2*3    // (k==2?3:0)+j, the expected bit
                    &1           // extract the bit
                    ?j:3         // space or not space
                ];

    for (auto j:v) std::cout<<j<<'\n'; // output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript <s>137</s> 133

```
r=(x,i=0,o='')=>{for(m of x){c="ŞHŦŬxļ>ňžŸ".charCodeAt(m)>>1<<i
for(j=3;j--;)o+=c&256>>j?'|_'[j%2]:' '}
return i<7?r(x,i+3,o+"\n"):o}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 188 bytes

```javascript
s=>[0,1,2].map(i=>s.replace(/./g,e=>[(t=(h,j='|',k=' ')=>(''+h).includes(e)?j:k)(2370+(b='5689'),' _ ','   '),t(104+b)+t(234+b,'_')+t(2347890),t(12680)+t(230+b,'_')+t(3704+b)][i])).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLboMwFET3/Qp291q4jh8Y7EqmHxKhhBAnMaEYxbSr/jt1H1I3o5nRmRn7jz4Nj7Csz3M8@@3ituTaPaeCyo699QsG1yb28MvUDx53bHelPgO4OrzR0cEn0LuDAohrEaC8ERbmYXo/@4SevI4vd4JSNbzEkwNdGwuEQnEoIGuRV3RFwavyRMo1c9lQOMBfaIzlP4CsDf/t@D@QT7933T50hLAxhvn4dNyGOKc4eTbFK14QhNSyMcpqI63Qlkuh60pJpVVdASHbFw)

Not the shortest but uses a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 329 bytes

```c
#define A 95:32
#define B '|':32
#define C s[0][k])?
#define I index(
#define P printf(
a;n;k;
main(c,s)char**s;{s++;a=strlen(*s);for(k=0;k<=a;k==a?k=0,n>4?k=2*a:n++:k++){!n&&P" %c  ",!I"14",C A);n==2&&P"%c%c%c ",!I"1237",C B,!I"170",C A,!I"56",C B);n==4&&P"%c%c%c ",!I"134579",C B,!I"147",C A,!I"2",C B);n&1?P"\n"),n++,k=-1:0;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NboMwEITvPIXjKgRjI/FjQsF1UZJTbtzTHCwHUuTUrXCkVkrz6nUBNbRStYfdmdlPuzI4Smnt3aFuWl2DFcjTIomdm16Dxefir7EBZhfud2qPysnbglYf6g9vMirw1rX63HiOYJop5ryIVnuSGCSfRef7hl0Mxkxwc@5OtfZ8g1jz2nmKh0w9cMEU56LsFdGPtO@xLwqNcaEwRpeZdt0KgrkEAJLZFkYUkg1YIaY5j4doLof6CeMkG@L1KLJwXB3mdDnaI0X/UQlNs/yXo9nExTfMjcoKPmmISP8ZUTyIipBdr9basD9K02V2n4dfsjmJo7HB@zc)

Comment: [274 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY1fS8MwFMXf9yniFSX/Cm2Xrm4x@jzwoe86RujaWTKjNIN2s/rRzdLhRO7DPZzz45wy2pal99ebqm5shZa4J1eN3VQ97rl5pm5FJpesQHYYPtrG7ms8sdJIelRPgNbA6WEUQxCdghs3HgL5phuLNXekfNUtpU5@1u8t1srt211lMWXMEWnulZZGKf1oVMztgwg/pXphGVsYxkgBKJQh4Ee2xJAIIISnUYE6fjgb6TQH8hvmcZBnO5uNnPjHTUWWz/9IkV/IdAST2@8CXizwsMqNihIiv7z3cWgX2Sy/m8c/Zb3TW@ej7gQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, <s>307</s> 301 bytes

```
@echo off&!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0&&exit/b&set/px=&set n= _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ 1 1  1 _1 _11_11_ 1_   11_11_11_1  11_  _1  1 _11_1  11_1 _1
for %%i in (0,3,6)do set t=&set j=0&call:l %%i&echo ␛[m!t:1=^|!
exit/b
:l
set/ad=3*!x:~%j%,1!+%~10,j+=1
set t=%t%!n:~%d%,3!&if .!x:~%j%! neq . goto:l
exit/b
```

`␛` represents the nonprintable "" character and is used to make sure the first line is blank when the input only has `1`s and `4`s.

Answer (score -1):

Perl, 145 characters

```
$i=<>;for$s(6,3,0){for($i=~/./g){$v=(175,9,158,155,57,179,183,137,191,187)[$_]>>$s;$o.=($v&4?'|':$").($v&2?'_':$").($v&1?'|':$")}$o.="
"}print$o
```

Ungolfed:

```
# Read STDIN
$i = <>;
# Amount to bit shift later
for $s (6,3,0)
{
  # For each character C from STDIN
  for ($i =~ /./g)
  {
    # Get the Cth array index, bit shifted right by $s
    $v = (175, 9, 158, 155, 57, 179, 183, 137, 191, 187)[$_]>>$s;
    # Concatenate each character if the bitwise masked value says it should be there
    $o .= ($v & 4 ? '|' : $") .
          ($v & 2 ? '_' : $") .
          ($v & 1 ? '|' : $");
  }
  # Concatenate a newline
  $o .= "
";
}
# Print the result
print $o;
```