# Emulate a 7-segment display

Tags: code-golf

## Task

The task is to display any of the 128 possible states of a
[7-segment display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display).

Your program should accept a string of 7 characters ("bits") that are either `0` or `1`.
First bit of input corresponds to segment A of the following illustration, the
second to B, etc (ignore `dp`):

[image: 7seg]

How you represent the display is up to you -- a single Unicode or ASCII symbol,
[ASCII art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/997/render-digital-clock-style-numbers), grafically, or whatever you can come up with. However, each
input must have it's own distinct output. If you come up with something fancy I'm sure you can harvest upvotes by showing off some examples.

All 128 possible states of the display are:

[image: states]

## Rules

- Codegolf
- As I said, any kind of output is allowed, but it would be nice if you specified it.
- Input can be stdin or command line argument.

## Examples

#### Input

```
1101101
```

#### Output

As ASCII/Unicode:

```
2
```

Different kinds of ASCII art (I'm not too good at this)

```
 _   ╺┓  ╒╗   ---
 _|  ┏┛  ╔╝     |
|_   ┗╸  ╚╛   ---
              |
              ---
```

Comment: Closely related to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/997/render-digital-clock-style-numbers   ?

Comment: @DavidCarraher: They're related, yes; I even linked to it myself. However, this is slightly harder I would say, as you have 118 more 'numbers' to generate. Most(?) of the answers to the other question would not work here, or would have to be heavily rewritten. Also, here you don't need to encode the different numbers, so other optimizations shuld be possible.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: it is a requirement that we use the encoding you provided? e.g. "1101101" should always represent "2" ?

Comment: @ardnew: yes. The position of the bits in input should map to the alphabetical order of the segments A to G in the first picture.

Comment: @Daniero In case the program uses an external resource, should the size of that resource be added to the total character (byte) count?

Comment: @w0lf I'll say that loading images and graphics externally is OK. Loading external scripts, or other resources that handle logic etc, is not.

Comment: Voting to close as "needs details or clarity" because the output format is very vague, approaching that of a popularity contest.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms "Approaching that of a popularity contest".  Popularity contests need rules too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### J (51)

```
1 2 1#"1[5 3$' #'{~,|:>0;(88707#:~7#7){>".&.>1!:1[1
```

output:

```
1101101
 ## 
   #
 ## 
#   
 ##
```

Comment: This can be shaved down to 38 char with a little effort: `1 2 1#"1' #'{~5 3$,0,.502 A.".&>1!:1]1`.

Answer (score 16):

### C, 106

**Size is 74 chars if allowed to rename program "W00WG5WW1GW66WG4WW2GW33WG"**

```
main(int i,char**s){
    for(s[0]="W00WG5WW1GW66WG4WW2GW33WG";i=*s[0]++;putchar(s[1][i&7]-49?i==71?10:32:42));
}
```

running:

```
./a.out 1101101
 ** 
   *
 ** 
*   
 **
```

notes:

'W' and 'G' (0x47 and 0x57) are chosen such that the value & 7 = 7, i.e they safely index the null character that terminates the input string.

Answer (score 15):

### Brainfuck - 224

```
++++++++++[>+>+++<<-]
>>++>,>,>,>,>,>,>,
<<<<<<<.
>[<+.->-]<<.
>>
>>>>>[<<<<<+<+>>>>>>-]<<<<<<.>[<->-]<.>>[<<+.->>-]<<<.>.
>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<+.->>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<.
>>>>>>[<<<<+<+>>>>>-]<<<<<.>[<->-]<.
>>>[<<<+.->>>-]<<<<.>.
>>>>[<<<<+.>]
```

Prints using Exlamation points:

```
 ! 
! !
 !
! !
 !
```

Not the most readable, but not too horrible either.

Surprised at how close this is to not being last place.

Answer (score 13):

## Postscript <strike>121</strike> 107

```
1 12 moveto{}5 0{0 -5 rmoveto}0 5 0 5 -5 0 0 -5 0 -5 5 0
n{49 eq{rlineto}{rmoveto}ifelse exec}forall stroke
```

requires `n` to be defined as the string to process so invoke like

```
gs -g7x14 -sn=1101101 lcd.ps
```

to get

[image: image of number two]

the complete set is

[image: complete set of characters]

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica: <s>135</s> <s>129</s> 118, image display

```
Image[MorphologicalComponents@Import@"http://goo.gl/j3elE" /. 
      Thread[Range@7 -> IntegerDigits[#, 2, 7][[{7, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4}]]]] &
```

spaces added "for clarity"

[image]

**Edit**

For those picky fellow site users: Without using an external mask:

```
Image[MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@Rasterize@8, CornerNeighbors -> False] /. 
    Thread[Range@7 ->IntegerDigits[#, 2, 7][[{7, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4}]]]] &
```

Comment: The code appears to be incomplete. I don't think you wanted your program to terminate with `&`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher It's a _function_,so it ends with `&`.

Comment: Yes, but it is not applied to anything.  How does one obtain output?

Comment: @DavidCarraher `i = Import@"http://goo.gl/j3elE"; r = Range@7;
Image[MorphologicalComponents@i /. 
     Thread[r -> {7, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4}] /. 
    Thread[r -> IntegerDigits[#, 2, 7]]] & /@ Range[0, 11]`

Comment: Importing code from the internet is abuse of the rules -1

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm not importing any code. Click on the link and see what you get

Comment: @belisarius I still don't like the fact that you embed external ressources.

Comment: @FUZxxl At least, delete your previous comment, since it's misleading and add another one properly targeted towards  your preferences.

Comment: I think it does not make any sense to remove my previous comment as that would make it much harder for somebody else to follow this discussion. You import external data which is funny as a joke but not part of a serious code golf answer. -1

Comment: @DavidCarraher If you follow the comments thread you'll understand my POV about this site :)

Comment: @belisarius Yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: Does this work for you? `Rasterize[Style[8, FontFamily -> "Synchro LET"], RasterSize -> 75, ImageSize -> 200]`

Comment: @dude I don't have that font installed. But it looks nice in the images available on the Internet.

Answer (score 10):

### APL, <s>58</s> 55

```
' _|'[1+3 3⍴0,x[1],0,(x←1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1')[6 7 2 5 4 3]]
```

Example input:

```
1101101
```

Output:

```
 _ 
 _|
|_
```

---

`⍞='1'` takes the input as a character array and converts it to a numeric array.

`1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1'` converts that array to: `0` for blank, `1` for `_`, `2` for `|`

`(x←1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1')[6 7 2 5 4 3]` assign that array to variable `x` and reorder to represent segments F, G, B, E, D, C

`0,x[1],0,(x←1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1')[6 7 2 5 4 3]` concatenates a blank, segment A and another blank to the front

`3 3⍴0,x[1],0,(x←1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1')[6 7 2 5 4 3]` reshape to a 3x3 matrix

`1+3 3⍴0,x[1],0,(x←1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1')[6 7 2 5 4 3]` converts to 1-based indexing

Finally uses the string `' _|'` to convert indicies into characters

---

### Edit

```
' _|'[1+3 3⍴(0,1 2 2 1 2 2 1×⍞='1')[1 2 1 7 8 3 6 5 4]]
```

Shaved off 3 chars by concatenating a `0` to front the array and using duplicate indicies, preventing a variable assignment

Comment: Iff your APL supports it, I think the *from* function `{` is 1-char shorter than bracket indexing `[]`.

Answer (score 9):

### PHP 66 bytes

```
<?for(;11>$i;)echo++$i&3?$argv[1][md5(¡æyÚ.$i)%8]?$i&1?~ƒ:_:~ß:~õ;
```

A slight improvement using an `md5` magic formula, but requires 3 additional binary bytes:
`¡`, `æ`, and `Ú` are characters 161, 230, and 218 respectively. It should work as is if copied directly, and saved as an ANSI format.

---

### PHP 73 (70) bytes

```
<?for($s=327638584;3<$s;)echo++$i&3?$argv[1][7&$s/=8]?$i&1?'|':_:' ':'
';
```

If you'll allow me three binary characters, this can be reduced to **70 bytes**:

```
<?for($s=327638584;3<$s;)echo++$i&3?$argv[1][7&$s/=8]?$i&1?~ƒ:_:~ß:~õ;
```

where `ƒ`, `ß`, and `õ` are characters 131, 223, and 245 respectively.

Receives input as a command line argument. Sample usage:

```
$ php seven-seg.php 1101101
 _
 _|
|_

$ php seven-seg.php 0111011

|_|
 _|
```

Comment: i tried to run your code, but am getting loads of error :( i dont understand your logic but seems interesting.

Comment: @D34dman The only messages it will produce are notices (undefined variables, etc). These can either be turned off in `php.ini` (by default they already are), or for testing, you can prepend the following code to the script: `<? error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ?>`

Comment: awesome! i got it working :D naice!

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript + jQuery + HTML + CSS (<s>210</s> 201)

This solution uses CSS sprites and [the image provided as an example](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/7-segment.svg/220px-7-segment.svg.png):

#### HTML (3)

```html
<a>
```

#### CSS (<s>82</s> 71)

Thanks to [xem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10732/xem) for the "*background:url*" trick:

```css
a{background:url(//bit.ly/VesRKL);width:13px;height:23px;display:block}
```

#### JavaScript (125 after removing newlines added here for readability)

```js
i=prompt();
x=-parseInt(i.substr(0,3),2)*23;
y=-parseInt(i.substr(3),2)*13.75;
$('a').css('background-position',y+'px '+x+'px');
```

---

Online test: http://jsfiddle.net/zhqJq/3/

Comment: Hey, but what about the 17.937 bytes of the image?? ;)

Comment: @ThomasW. I don't know whether that should be counted as well. Let's leave this to the OP to decide.

Comment: You could use `<p>` tag and avoid `display:block` on CSS to save space

Comment: background-image:url(http://bit.ly/VesRKL); => background:url(//bit.ly/VesRKL);

Comment: @xem thanks for the tip; I've edited my answer

Answer (score 6):

## R (65 chars):

```
plot((3^(1i*1.5:-4.5)*(1:7!=7)),col=strsplit(readline(),'')[[1]])
```

Relies on some loose approximations for some transcendental nuumbers ...

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2 - 65

```
s=raw_input()+'0\n'
for i in`0x623C239E38D2EAA1`:print s[int(i)],
```

Example:

```
echo 1101101|python2 7seg.py
0 1 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 0 
1 0 0 
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 5):

**PostScript: <strike>53 binary, 87 ASCII</strike> 52 binary, 86 ASCII**

Hexdump of the program using binary tokens:

```
$ hexdump -C lcd_binary.ps 
00000000  28 34 34 30 34 30 38 30  34 30 34 30 30 30 30 34  |(440408040400004|
00000010  30 34 30 34 34 34 34 34  38 34 38 30 38 29 7b 7d  |0404444484808){}|
00000020  92 49 6e 7b 92 70 31 92  04 92 96 92 6b 92 63 92  |.In{.p1.....k.c.|
00000030  a7 7d 92 49                                       |.}.I|
00000034
```

[Download this file](http://www.mediafire.com/?vs6te3yueiig2r1) to try it out.

Using ASCII tokens:

```
(4404080404000040404444484808){}forall
n{not 1 and setgray moveto lineto stroke}forall
```

First `forall` loop puts all required coordinates on the stack. The coordinates are stored in a string to minimize required space. The coordinates are in reverse order, i.e. the last 4 chars are for segment A. We draw a line from `(0,8)` to `(4,8)` for this segment (actually, we have to add 48 to all coordinates, because `forall` puts all ASCII codes on the stack).

The second `forall` loops through all the `0`s and `1`s in the input string and turns them into a gray value. `0`s are drawn white (gray value 1) and `1`s are drawn black (gray value 0). Then we use the coordinates that the first `forall` loop left on the stack to draw the lines.

Invoke the program using Ghostscript, just like Geoff Reedy's:

```
gs -sn=1101101 lcd.ps
```

This displays: [image: Sample output]

Comment: I think you can replace `neg 49 add` (which is awesome btw) with `1 and`.

Comment: @luserdroog: Brilliant, bitwise operators, haven't thought of them. But it has to be `not 1 and`, right? Still saves one byte in both ASCII and binary.

Comment: I feel there's gotta be a neat way with a 1bit bitmap. but `bitshift` is such a long word.

Comment: But it's only a two byte binary token

Comment: Yeah. But it still feels like a *cheat* to me somehow. :) I feel I need to do as much as possible with readable source before resorting to binary.

Comment: You know, if the code isn't ascii, then the data doesn't need to be ascii, either....

Answer (score 4):

### APL <s>101 86 73</s> 69

```
m←45⍴' '⋄m[¯40+⎕av⍳(⍎∊3/' ',¨⍕⍞)/')*+16;EJOQRSAFK-27=>?']←'⎕'⋄9 5⍴m
```

Input is from the screen via ⍞

```
1101101
```

Which produces a 9x5 character matrix composed of blanks and ⎕ as follows:

```
 ⎕⎕⎕
     ⎕
     ⎕
     ⎕
 ⎕⎕⎕
⎕
⎕
⎕
 ⎕⎕⎕
```

The seven digit number is converted into a partition vector to select the ⎕ co-ordinates.

Comment: My head hurts...

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica <s>112</s> <s>103</s> <s>100</s> <s>96</s> 88, using Graphs

```
HighlightGraph[z=GridGraph@{3,2},Pick[EdgeList[z][[{3,4,1,2,6,7,5}]],Characters@#,"1"]]&
```

[image]

```
Using it to show a calculator display

l = {7-> 7, 1-> 6, 0-> 63, 8-> 127, 9-> 111,3 -> 79, 5-> 109,  2-> 91, 4-> 102, 6-> 125}; 
GraphicsRow[
  HighlightGraph[z = GridGraph[{3,2}, EdgeStyle-> {White}, GraphHighlightStyle-> {"Thick"}], 
    EdgeList[z][[{3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 5}]][[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 7] Range@7]]] & /@
            (IntegerDigits[8736302] /. l)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What sort of input do you expect? Neither `[123]` nor ["123"], nor `IntegerDigits[123]` work for me.  I get only `z`, with no highlighting.

Comment: @dude Try `HighlightGraph[z = GridGraph@{3, 2}, 
   Pick[EdgeList[z][[{3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 5}]], Characters@#, 
    "1"]] &@"1111111"`` :)

Answer (score 3):

### Python (107)

Definitely more golfable.

```
a=map(int,raw_input())
for i in(0,6,3):print' .. '*a[i]+('\n'+' .'[a[5-i/6]]+'  '+' .'[a[1+i/6]])*(2*(i!=3))
```

Output:

```
1101101
 .. 
   .
   .
 .. 
.   
.   
 ..
```

Explanation:

```
a is a list of booleans extracted from the input.
When you multiply a string with a number, it will return the string repeated (number) times.
If that number happens to be zero, it returns an empty string.
i is iterated through 0 (pos A), 6 (pos G), and 3 (pos D).
' .. ' will print either section A, G, or D, depending on the value of i.
([string here])*(2*(i!=3)) will print [string here] twice only if i!=3.
Breaking down [string here]:
 - '\n' will print a newline for each repetition.
 - '  ' is the null space between horizontal sections.
 - ' .'[(bool)] will return either ' ' if (bool) is 0, and '.' if (bool) is 1.
 - 5-i/6 will return 5 if i=0 and 4 if i=6. a[5] is section F and a[4] is section E.
 - 1+i/6 will return 1 if i=0 and 2 if i=6. a[1] is section B and a[2] is section C.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7 (93 chars):

```
print (' {0}\n{5} {1}\n {6}\n{4} {2}\n {3}').format(*map(lambda x:int(x)and'*'or' ',raw_input()))
```

#### Explanation:

With the stdin input, use a makeshift ternary operator to give `*` for true and a space for false.  Take those values and plug them into a format statement that's in the format of the 7 digit display.  It'd be at most 83 characters if the display worked like this:

```
 a
b c
 d
e f
 g
```

but the ordering makes it longer.  Anyone have a way around this?

#### Example:

```
$ ./7seg.py
111000

 *
  *

  *

$ ./7seg.py


1111111

 *
* *
 *
* *
 *
```

Comment: Nice, but that lambda seems unnecessary: `print' {0}\n{5} {1}\n {6}\n{4} {2}\n {3}'.format(*[' *'[i=='1']for i in raw_input()])` ;) No need for brackets and space for the print statement either.

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know you could put booleans in indexers.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Np. Also, `>'0'` instead of `=='1'` and ``input()`` (with backticks around, but that won't show up because of the formatting here) instead of `raw_input()`.

Comment: fyi, you can use tripple backticks if you need backticks in the code ```x = `input()` ```

Comment: Cool. Then I learned something today too :)

Answer (score 3):

I thought we needed a lispy answer...

## Clojure, 159 chars

```
(print(apply str(flatten(interpose\newline(partition 3(map(fn[x](if(= x\1)\o" "))(str" "(apply str(interpose" "(map(vec(read-line))[0 5 1 6 4 2 3])))" ")))))))
```

The above will run in the REPL and provide the correct answer. For example:

```
1111111
 o 
o o
 o 
o o
 o
```

Throwing numbers at it with small modifications:

```
(doseq [i ["1111110" "0110000" "1101101" "1111001" "0110011" "1011011" "1011111" "1110000" "1111111" "1111011"]]
(println (apply str(flatten(interpose\newline(partition 3(map(fn[x](if(= x\1)\o" "))(str" "(apply str(interpose" "(map(vec i)[0 5 1 6 4 2 3])))" "))))))) 
(println))
```

yields:

```
 o 
o o

o o
 o 


  o

  o


 o 
  o
 o 
o  
 o 

 o 
  o
 o 
  o
 o 


o o
 o 
  o


 o 
o  
 o 
  o
 o 

 o 
o  
 o 
o o
 o 

 o 
  o

  o


 o 
o o
 o 
o o
 o 

 o 
o o
 o 
  o
 o 

nil
```

Not easy to read, but they're there!

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript 123

```
s=prompt(i=o='');for(m=' 0516423';i++<15;i%3==0?o+='\n':1)o+=' ─│'[~i%2&(A=+s[+m[~~(i/2)]])+(A&+'110'[i%3])];console.log(o)
```

I can bring the character count lower (101) if we use only one character for the "on" state, but it is less legible:

```
s=prompt(i=o='');for(m=' 0516423';i++<15;i%3==0?o+='\n':1)o+=' ■'[~i%2&s[+m[~~(i/2)]]];console.log(o)
```

Comment: +1 This is impressive. I'm still trying to reverse-engineer it. It's taught me a few things already!

Answer (score 2):

## Postscript 136

Not winner, but a different approach.

```
15 string exch{1 and 255 mul}forall
[7 3 9 13 11 5 1]{count 1 sub index 3 1 roll exch put}forall
3 5 8[.02 0 0 .05 0 0]{}image showpage
```

Expects the input string to be on the stack:

```
$ echo '(1101101)'|cat - 7seg.ps |gs -sDEVICE=png16 -sOutputFile=6c.png -
```

This one's even worse. **294** to make a "binary" bitmap. I took me a while to remember that each row is padded to an even byte. So a 3x5 bitmap is five bytes with the 3 msb bits significant.

```
2#1101101
(12345)exch
2 copy 64 and 0 exch put %A
2 copy 2 and 6 bitshift 2 index 32 and or 1 exch put %F B
2 copy 1 and 6 bitshift 2 exch put %G
2 copy 4 and 5 bitshift 2 index 16 and 1 bitshift or 3 exch put %E C
2 copy 8 and 3 bitshift 4 exch put
pop
3 5 1[.02 0 0 .02 0 0]{}image showpage
```

Output is just as ugly as the other one. :(

Alright here's one that looks good. **190**

Edit: It was upside-down and backwards. Fixed now.

```
(1101101)
{neg 49 add 255 mul
1 string dup 0 4 3 roll put}forall
(\377){@/g/f/e/d/c/b/a}{exch def}forall
@ a a @
b @ @ f
b @ @ f
@ g g @
c @ @ e
c @ @ e
@ d d @
4 7 8[.01 0 0 .01 0 0]{}image showpage
```

Comment: This shows me some funny patterns. Is there still a bug somewhere?

Comment: hmm. yeah. (1111110) does not look like a zero. It's just an enlarged bytemap. I guess boxes is oversimplified. :(

Comment: it's kindof in the nature of this bitmap approach, I think. I'm not sure how to make it not ugly.

Comment: Some light commentary available [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/Rvu76u4AxQU/discussion).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 264

Getting the output to look right required many bytes, so no cigar this time.
But here's the verbose (264 chars) code anyway.

```
{a, b, c, d, e, g} = {{-1, 5}, {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 3}};
f@n_ := Graphics[{Yellow, Thickness[.1], CapForm["Round"],
   Line /@ {{g, c}, {g, a}, {g, e}, {e, d}, {d, c}, {c, b}, {b, a}}[[Flatten@
   Position[IntegerDigits[n, 2, 7], 1]]]}, 
   Background -> Blue, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {1, 5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 1]
```

The complete set of characters:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[f[p], {p, 0, 128}], 16]]
```

[image: characteris]

The digits:

```
{f[63], f[6], f[91], f[79], f[102], f[109], f[125], f[7], f[127], f[111]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**PHP - 155 characters**

```
<?php
$y=array("   \n"," - \n","   \n","  |\n","|  \n","| |\n"); $x = $argv[1]; echo $y[$x[0]].$y[2*$x[6]+$x[2]+2].$y[$x[7]].$y[2*$x[5]+$x[3]+2].$y[$x[4]];
```

it would be 150 characters if we use php 5.4 type array declaration, but i dont have that installed on my laptop so couldn't test it.

**Sample out puts.**

[image]

**Explanation:**

First i divided the 7 segment display to Five rows and 3 columns. With 1st, 3rd and 5th row havimg '-' in the middle column, and space otherwise.

The 2nd and 4th row has a pipe '|' character in the first and last column. Now the presence of these character should be guided by the input values.

I created a lookup table, which is basically two lookup table. First one for the calculation of values for 1st, 3rd and 5th row. And another one at offset 2 ( 3rd item ) for calculation of rows 2nd and 4th.

Answer (score 2):

## Java - 204 characters

```java
class A{public static void main(String[]a){char[]c=new char[7];for(int i=0;i<7;i++)c[i]=a[0].charAt(i)==49?i%3==0?95:'|'):32;System.out.printf(" %c %n%c%c%c%n%c%c%c",c[0],c[5],c[6],c[1],c[4],c[3],c[2]);}}
```

Sample output:

```java
 _ 
 _|
|_
```

Formatted properly:

```java
class A {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        char[] c = new char[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            c[i] = a[0].charAt(i) == 49 ? (i % 3 == 0 ? 95 : '|') : 32;
        System.out.printf(" %c %n%c%c%c%n%c%c%c", c[0], c[5], c[6], c[1], c[4], c[3], c[2]);
    }
}
```

Really wish I could avoid that for loop, but I tried a few other things and they were all longer.  There's probably a better way to do this, but this is my first attempt at code golf.  (And Java's like the worst language for it, which is why I thought it would be interesting.)  Even Brainfuck has me beat, but at least my output looks nicer.

EDIT: can get rid of "public" on class, saves me 7 chars!

And thanks, daniero, for showing me printf! (18 chars saved)

Rewrote the output format, changed character literals to decimal, 12 chars saved.

Comment: Welcome to codegolf.se! Java introduced a `printf` method a few versions back, which is basically `println` and `format` in one (like the C function); This will save you some characters,

Comment: Here's another trick: You can combine the "body" of the `for` loop and the update part into one, saving one character: `for(int i=7;i>0;c[--i]=a[0].charAt(i)==49?(i%3==0?95:'|'):32);`

Answer (score 1):

### VBA - 263

It's ugly but it works, I think. I am having trouble viewing the proper bit order, so I'm inferring from others' answers. Even if that piece is wrong, the code length should remain the same.

```
Sub d(b)
Dim c(1 To 7)
For a=1 To 7
c(a)=Mid(b,a,1)
Next
x=" - "
y="|"
z=" "
w="   "
v=vbCr
MsgBox IIf(c(1)=1,x,w) & v & IIf(c(6)=1,y,z) & z & IIf(c(2)=1,y,z) & v & IIf(c(7)=1,x,w) & v & IIf(c(5)=1,y,z) & z & IIf(c(3)=1,y,z) & v & IIf(c(4)=1,x,w)End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**VBScript - 178 characters**

```
m=Split("2 7 11 10 9 5 6")
s=" _ "&vbCr&"|_|"&vbCr&"|_|"
For x=1 To 7
If Mid(WScript.Arguments.Item(0),x,1)=0 Then r=m(x-1):s=Left(s,r-1)&" "&Right(s,Len(s)-r)
Next
MsgBox s
```

Comment: Thanks!  Couple bonehead mistakes cost me 6 characters. I can almost get this down to the size of the VBA one even with the absurdly long call to get the function line argument.

Comment: Unless your code is functional without the newline characters, you have to count them too. This has 178 characters according to my count.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 188 characters

Note that the one has to *type* 188 characters if only including mandatory whitespace -- the IDE expands it out when you copy it into the VBA editor.

```vba
Sub f(i)
Dim c() As Byte
m=Split("1 6 10 9 8 4 5")
c=StrConv(" _  |_| |_|",128)
c(3)=10
c(7)=10
For x=1 To 7
If Mid(i,x,1) = 0 Then c(m(x-1))=32
Next
MsgBox StrConv(c,64)
End Sub
```

Sadly, VBScript doesn't have a strongly typed Byte array, or that one could be much shorter using this method.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam - 29

```
l0N]s7078571876784728737Ab\f=
```

CJam is a new language I am developing, similar to GolfScript - http://sf.net/p/cjam. Here is the explanation:

`l` reads a line from the input
`0` is the number 0
`N` is a variable preinitialized to the newline string
`]` gathers the elements on the stack into an array
`s` converts a value (the array) to string, thus appending a zero and a newline to the given input
`7078571876784728737` is a number (the same number I used in python, but it was in hex there)
`A` is a variable preinitialized to 10
`b` does a base conversion, generating the array [7 0 7 8 ... 3 7]
`\` swaps the last two values on the stack
`f=` applies the `=` operator (here, indexed array access) on the input string (plus zero and newline) and each number 7, 0, 7, ...
The index 7 corresponds to the appended zero, and 8 corresponds to the appended newline.

My python solution does exactly the same thing (except the digit separation is done via string conversion)

Comment: What am I looking at here? Care to offer a brief explanation of the code?

Comment: @daniero I added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ECMAScript 2016) - 108 bytes

```
console.log(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]=[...prompt()].map((x,i)=>+x?'_||'[i%3]:' '),` ${a}
${f}${g}${b}
${e}${d}${c}`))
```

This *probably* can be golfed further, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site! That's a nice first entry :)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 148 bytes

```javascript
e=>(e[0]==1?" #\n":"\n")+(e[5]==1?"#":" ")+(e[1]==1?" #\n":"\n")+(e[6]==1?" #\n":"\n")+(e[4]==1?"#":" ")+(e[2]==1?" #\n":"\n")+(e[3]==1?" #\n":"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcvLCsIwEAXQXyntIgnWYH0hhujOn1AXIZ2UlJLUPLoRvz0GumxnceEe7vRiEl46PYatsS2knifgNwzP3Zvz5l4W1cuU1zIH2WQ9zVplKmZpVnfnVT0uvveru8NCE5uEK5TnDj5RO8BIeUSY8tSBaB96yEK1GWOgQVtUoxjUBdUqGpm7wVBL8pXWeDsAHWyHeywJYT/CUjPfHw) <sub>(Footer is Node.js to read `.input.tio`)</sub>

Accepts input of ABCDEFG in binary flags and returns:

```javascript
 #
# #
 #
# #
 #
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 136 bytes

```
DIM A[7,2]COPY A,@L@L?DATA.,1,1,3,4,3,6,1,4,0,1,0,3,1INPUT X$FOR I=0TO 6M=I MOD 3GBOX A[I,1],A[I,0],A[I,1]+!M,A[I,0]+!!M,-VAL(X$[I])NEXT
```

Output is graphical.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 5.6, 65 bytes plain ASCII

```php
for(;$p++<9;)echo$argn[_707561432[$p]]?"||_"[$p%3]:" ","\n"[$p%3];
```

or, without a trailing linebreak, but with some bitwise fun:

```php
for(;$p++<11;)echo$argn[_70785618432[$p]]?L|Sx[$p&1]:a^kAAA[$p&3];
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b2187c98212f4ce1abd0749028b641b13069546).

**breakdown 1**

```php
for(;$p++<9;)echo           # loop through positions
    $argn[_707561432[$p]]   # map position to input bit
        ?"||_"[$p%3]            # if set: underscore in 2nd column, pipe symbol else
        :" "                    # else space
    ,"\n"[$p%3]             # add newline every 3 columns
;
```

**breakdown 2**

```php
for(;$p++<11;)echo          # loop through positions
    $argn[_70785618432[$p]] # map position to input bit (bit 8 for EOL, never set)
        ?L|Sx[$p&1]             # if set: underscore in the middle, pipe symbol else
        :a^kAAA[$p&3]           # else: newline in 4th column, space else
```

Comment: Whether the language is new or old doesn't matter anymore [since the Summer of 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges). So you won't have to mention non-competing.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks I missed that. But it´s also a nice challenge to revive old PHP versions; it also sometimes gives a different view on more recent features: I found, on occasions, that the "old" way is more efficient (in size, in performance, in readability and sometimes all three) than using stuff that was added to PHP later No golfing advantage in this case, though: The first approach would require 8 extra bytes, the second one 5.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
C₄+ç
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@VFTi/bh5f//GxoagBAA) or [verify all possible inputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9oZOHml2SedXiDgZWLvZLCo7ZJCkr2/50fNbVoH17@X@c/AA).

See the *verify all possible inputs* link above to see the mapping used for each input.

**Explanation:**

This abuses the rules where it states:

> How you represent the display is up to you -- **a single Unicode or ASCII symbol**, ASCII art, grafically, or whatever you can come up with. However, **each input must have it's own distinct output.**

```python
C       # Convert the (implicit) input from binary to integer
 ₄+     # Increase it by 1000
   ç    # Convert it to a unicode character with this value (and output implicitly)
```

---

Alternative more in the spirit of the challenge using the output-format:

```
 -
| |
 -
| |
 -
```

#### 38 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):

```
Σ•L7×•Nè}εi" -| | "14∍2ôNèëðº]J24S5∍£»
```

Can definitely be golfed..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OJHDYt8zA9PB1J@h1fUntuaqaSgW6NQo6BkaPKoo9fo8Bag8OHVhzcc2hXrZWQSbAoUPLT40O7//w0NDUAIAA) or [verify all possible inputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9oZOHml2SedXiDgZWLzv9zix81LPIxPzwdSPkdXlF7bmumkoJujUKNgpKhyaOOXqPDW4DCh1cf3nBoV22tl5FJsClQ9NDiQ7v/6/wHAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ       }          # Sort the (implicit) input-digits by:
 •L7×•Nè           #  The digit at the same index in the compressed integer 1367524
                   #   i.e. "1101101" → ["1","0","1","1","1","0","1"]
ε                  # Then map each digit to:
 i                 #  If it's a 1:
  " -| | "         #   Push string " -| | "
          14∍      #   Lengthen it to size 14: " -| |  -| |  -"
             2ô    #   Split it into parts of 2: [" -","| ","| "," -","| ","| "," -"]
               Nè  #   Index into it
 ë                 #  Else (it's a 0):
  ðº               #   Push "  " (two spaces) instead
    ]              # Close both the if-else and map
                   #  i.e. ["1","0","1","1","1","0","1"]
                   #   → [" -","  ","| "," -","| ","  "," -"]
J                  # Join everything together to a single string
                   #  i.e. [" -","  ","| "," -","| ","  "," -"] → " -  |  -|    -"
 24S               # Push [2,4]
    5∍             # Lengthened to size 5: [2,4,2,4,2]
      £            # Split the string into parts of that size
                   #  i.e. " -  |  -|    -" → [" -","  | "," -","|   "," -"]
       »           # Join by newlines (and output implicitly)
                   #  i.e. [" -","  | "," -","|   "," -"] → " -\n  | \n -\n|   \n -"
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (*section How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•L7×•` is `1367524`.