# Output the current time in ascii art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

## Challenge

Your task is to output the time (in 12 hour time) in ascii art.

All characters that will be used are as follows:

```
  ___    __   ___    ____    _  _     _____     __    ______ 
 / _ \  /_ | |__ \  |___ \  | || |   | ____|   / /   |____  |
| | | |  | |    ) |   __) | | || |_  | |__    / /_       / / 
| | | |  | |   / /   |__ <  |__   _| |___ \  | '_ \     / /  
| |_| |  | |  / /_   ___) |    | |    ___) | | (_) |   / /   
 \___/   |_| |____| |____/     |_|   |____/   \___/   /_/    

   ___     ___  
  / _ \   / _ \                                _
 | (_) | | (_) |   __ _ _ __    _ __ _ __     (_)
  > _ <   \__, |  / _` | '  \  | '_ \ '  \     _ 
 | (_) |    / /   \__,_|_|_|_| | .__/_|_|_|   (_)
  \___/    /_/                 |_|
```

(For each number/symbol individually, consult [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mathiasfoster/96d4f1bbc23cc35f71d4)).

You will receive input in an array of the form:

- `[hours, minutes, 'am/pm']`. For example, `[4, 57, 'am']`, with single quotes only used for am/pm
- or `"hours-minutes-am/pm"`. For example, `"4-56-am"`
- or `[hours, 'minutes', 'am/pm']` for languages that cannot handle leading zeroes on numbers. For example, `[4, '07', 'am']`

You may use either input method.

Output will be in the form `1  2 : 5  9 am`, where there is one initial space, two spaces between each number (in the gist, each number already has one space on each side), one space between : (colon) and the neighbouring numbers, and one space between the last number and `am/pm`, with an optional leading and/or trailing newline. All spaces are between the right-most point of the symbol on the left and the left-most point of the symbol on the right.

Implicit output is allowed.

Lowest byte size wins.

The `am/pm` are to be aligned such that the bottom of the `p` in `pm` is aligned with the bottom of the rest of the output, that is, the undercore denoting the top of `am/pm` starts on the third line down (not counting a leading newline).

The colon is to be aligned such that it's first character (an underscore) starts on the second line down (not counting a leading newline).

For `minutes < 10`, output the minutes with a leading `0` (you should receive this in the input). For example, `[8, 04, 'pm']` -> `8 : 0  4 pm`.

You must not fetch the data for the numbers from a library or external resource. All data must be contained within the program.

For example, for the input `[12, 47, 'am']`, the output would be as follows:

```
  __    ___          _  _      ______  
 /_ |  |__ \    _   | || |    |____  | 
  | |     ) |  (_)  | || |_       / /   __ _ _ __ 
  | |    / /    _   |__   _|     / /   / _` | '  \
  | |   / /_   (_)     | |      / /    \__,_|_|_|_|
  |_|  |____|          |_|     /_/
```

(If you see any edge cases that you can't decide what to do with, please post in comments and I will add them to examples).

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render "Digital Clock Style" Numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/997/render-digital-clock-style-numbers)

Comment: @Mego you reckon? That question simply says render (any) number as (very) basic ascii art. This question beefs up the ascii art, adds the am/pm and colon, and specifies input with an array with a mix of types.

Comment: Specifically: that question is clock-style numbers. This question is actual time, with all the right formatting.

Comment: The different format of the numbers and the addition of the colon and am/pm do little to differentiate the challenges imo. The main part of the challenge is still converting integers to ascii art.

Comment: So, `[12, 47, 'pm']` should output `12:47 am`?

Comment: @Mego I don't think this is a duplicate. The other challenge has that ultra simple formatting (even compressable as binary). This one will probably get more kolmogorov-complexity-like answers.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 aaargh! fixed. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: How do we receive arguments in languages without arrays?  Or with arrays but without tuples?  (Your example 'array' has elements of different types, unlike arrays in just about any language that exists)

Comment: @TobySpeight would "12-47-am" work in most languages?

Comment: @MathiasFoster I would recommend that you allow any input (within reason), but that you have the deciding vote on it, and if somebody uses input that trivialises the question, tell them and **enforce** it.

Comment: I guess the program has to output a leading 0 for the number of minutes, if needed? (e.g. `10, 9, 'am'` => `10:09am`). What about leading 0 for hours (e.g. `8, 9, 'am'`)? Have to insert 0? Have to insert a space? Have to insert either a space or zero? Can assume the input already contains the leading zero or space?

Comment: @anatolyg question updated. basically no leading 0 for hours, there is one for minutes but you'll receive it in the input, so treat it as normal.

Comment: Can we have trailing space in the output?

Comment: @JAtkin thats fine, as long as it looks exactly as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Perl, <s>592</s> <s>579</s> <s>540</s> <s>522</s> 510 bytes

Under a sector!

```
($L,$C,$b)=unpack"W/aW/aB*",q!12346677889999 _|/\)(
'<,>.` PP¨ 
¨@T @ôäð˜SÀ§€fÌU`à¨Àäð'€GÖf`3 X½`fÍ5 s Î|½`gËÖ— $¡))õ™˜À8Sô BÁªx~O àÔýåËþÏÃÆ~O‡ŸY¬Àf s 
½`À*õŸ/X8|½`p>^€<¯å­kgúºÖ·ÓÊ¸°ªÀj® kª¸•p¸å\×   ­ô!;@c=map{$i<<=$_-$P if$_>$P;$P=$_;sprintf"%${l}b",$i++}$L=~/./g;while($b){$b=~s/^$c[$_]// and$g.=($C=~/./sg)[$_]for 0..$#c}$_=pop;s/-/:/;y/apm-/;</d;for$a(0..5){map{$o.=substr((split$/,$g)[$a],($x=-48+ord)*12,('6356766766099'=~/./g)[$x]+3)}/./g;$o.=$/}print$o
```

This program expects the time in the 2nd format (*"12-34-am"*) as a commandline argument.

Commented:

```
($L,$C,$b) = unpack "W/aW/aB*",             # extract code lengths, chars, and bitstream
    q!12346677889999 _|/\)(
'<,>.` PP¨ 
¨@T @ôäð˜SÀ§€fÌU`à¨Àäð'€GÖf`3 X½`fÍ5 s Î|½`gËÖ— $¡))õ™˜À8Sô BÁªx~O àÔýåËþÏÃÆ~O‡ŸY¬Àf s 
½`À*õŸ/X8|½`p>^€<¯å­kgúºÖ·ÓÊ¸°ªÀj® kª¸•p¸å\×   ­ô!;
@c = map {                                  # reconstruct huffman prefix codes
    $i <<= $_-$P if $_ > $P;                # increase code size
    $P = $_;                                # keep track of previous code
    sprintf "%${l}b", $i++                  # append code as bitstring
}
$L=~/./g;                                   # canonical huffman prefix lengths
while ( $b ) {                              # decompress font
        $b =~ s/^$c[$_]//                   # match and strip prefix code
        and $g .= ($C=~/./sg)[$_]           # append char for prefix code
    for 0..$#c                              # iterate prefix codes in order
}                                           # luckily we can omit checking trailing bytes    

$_ = pop;                                   # get cmdline arg "12-34-am"    
s/-/:/;                                     # ord(':')-ord('0')=10
y/apm-/;</d;                                # 'a'-> chr(11), 'p' -> chr(12), strip -,m
for $a (0..5) {                             # iterate 6 output lines
    map {                                   # iterate each char in input
        $o .= substr(
            ( split $/, $g )[$a],           # grab line $a
            ( $x=-48+ord ) * 12,            # $x=glyph index, 12=glyph width
            ('6356766766099'=~/./g)[$x]+3   # glyph display width
        )
    } /./g;
    $o .= $/                                # append newline
}
print $o                                    # output
```

Note that due to character encoding issues, when you paste the above code in a file, the output may be somewhat malformed. So here's the golfed version, base-64 encoded. Copy it, and paste it into `base64 -d > 510.pl`:

```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```

Here's the font I'm using. I've spaced the glyphs 12 characters apart
(the size of the am/pm) for easy indexing.

```
   ___        __          ___         ____        _  _        _____         __        ______       ___         ___            
  / _ \      /_ |        |__ \       |___ \      | || |      | ____|       / /       |____  |     / _ \       / _ \      _  
 | | | |      | |           ) |        __) |     | || |_     | |__        / /_           / /     | (_) |     | (_) |    (_)          __ _ _ __   _ __ _ __ 
 | | | |      | |          / /        |__ <      |__   _|    |___ \      | '_ \         / /       > _ <       \__, |     _          / _` | '  \ | '_ \ '  \
 | |_| |      | |         / /_        ___) |        | |       ___) |     | (_) |       / /       | (_) |        / /     (_)         \__,_|_|_|_|| .__/_|_|_|
  \___/       |_|        |____|      |____/         |_|      |____/       \___/       /_/         \___/        /_/                              |_|
```

This font is 592 bytes.
The previous approach used a few variations on RLE compression to reduce this to 353 bytes, at the cost of 78 bytes decompression code.
The Huffman coding compresses the font to 221 bytes at the cost of 154 bytes for the decompression algorithm.

Comment: Darn it! I really want string compression for haskell..

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>932</s> 699 bytes

Yay, under 700 bytes!!

```hs
t=transpose
i=intercalate
l=lines
u=unlines
s=show
c(h,m,a)=u$t$l(i(r"!!\n!!\n")(map d(s h++':':(if m<10 then '0':s m else s m)))++r"!!"++(d$a!!0))
e s z n=i s$splitOn z n
r=e"   ""!"
d 'a'=b 10
d 'p'=b 11
d ':'=b 12
d n=b$read[n]
b n=splitOn(r"!!")(u$t$l$r$e" |""@"$e"___""$"$e"_|""~"$e"!!""*"$e"_ ""#""  $! __!$! $_! # _!  $__!  __! $$! $!  $*****  \n / #\\  /_@@_#\\ @$ \\ @@|@!| $~!/ /!|$#@  / #\\!/ #\\****!  #\n|@@@ @@! )@!__)@@@|@#@@__! / /_* / / @ (_)@@ (_)@  _###__! #_##__!(_)\n|@@@ @@!/ /!|_#< @__!~@$ \\ @ '#\\!  / /! > #<!\\__,@ / _`@ '  \\ @ '#\\ '  \\!#\n|@~@ @@  / /_!$)@!@@! $)@@ (_)@!/ /!@ (_)@! / /  \\__,~~~~@ .__/~~~ (_)\n \\$/!|~@$~@$_/! @~!|$_/!\\$/!/_/*\\$/! /_/**!@~** ")!!n
```

Somewhat ungolfed

```hs
module Clock where
import Data.Lists

main :: IO ()
main = putStr $ clock (5,05,"am")

clock :: (Int, Int, String) -> String
clock (h,m,a) | m <- if m < 10 then '0':show m else show m
              , hm <- intercalate "      \n      \n" (map digit (show h ++ ':' :m))
              =  unlines $ transpose $ lines (hm ++ "      "++(digit$a!!0))

digit :: Char -> String
digit 'a' = numbers 10
digit 'p' = numbers 11
digit ':' = numbers 12
digit n = numbers (read [n])


numbers :: Int -> String
numbers n = splitOn "      " (unlines $ transpose $ lines "  ___    __   ___    ____    _  _     _____     __    ______    ___     ___                                \n / _ \\  /_ | |__ \\  |___ \\  | || |   | ____|   / /   |____  |  / _ \\   / _ \\                             _ \n| | | |  | |    ) |   __) | | || |_  | |__    / /_       / /  | (_) | | (_) |  __ _ _ __    _ __ _ __   (_)\n| | | |  | |   / /   |__ <  |__   _| |___ \\  | '_ \\     / /    > _ <   \\__, | / _` | '  \\  | '_ \\ '  \\   _ \n| |_| |  | |  / /_   ___) |    | |    ___) | | (_) |   / /    | (_) |    / /  \\__,_|_|_|_| | .__/_|_|_| (_)\n \\___/   |_| |____| |____/     |_|   |____/   \\___/   /_/      \\___/    /_/                |_|             ") !! n
```

### How it works

(This is mostly how the ungolfed program works)

```hs
clock :: (Int, Int, String) -> String
clock (h,m,a) | m <- if m < 10 then '0':show m else show m
              , hm <- intercalate "      \n      \n" (map digit (show h ++ ':' :m))
              =  unlines $ transpose $ lines (hm ++ "      "++(digit$a!!0))
```

`clock` takes a tuple of the time and returns a string. `m` is the current minute with the leading `0` added if it is `<10`. `hm` is the hours and minutes joined with a `:`. The last thing it does is [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the output.

```hs
digit :: Char -> String
digit 'a' = numbers 10
digit 'p' = numbers 11
digit ':' = numbers 12
digit n = numbers (read [n])
```

Fairly simple here. `digit` is a function that maps the chars to locations in the stored string.

```hs
numbers :: Int -> String
numbers n = splitOn "      " (unlines $ transpose $ lines  replace" |""@"$replace"___""$"$replace"_|""~"$replace"!!""*"$replace"_ ""#""  $! __!$! $_! # _!  $__!  __! $$! $!  $*****  \n / #\\  /_@@_#\\ @$ \\ @@|@!| $~!/ /!|$#@  / #\\!/ #\\****!  #\n|@@@ @@! )@!__)@@@|@#@@__! / /_* / / @ (_)@@ (_)@  _###__! #_##__!(_)\n|@@@ @@!/ /!|_#< @__!~@$ \\ @ '#\\!  / /! > #<!\\__,@ / _`@ '  \\ @ '#\\ '  \\!#\n|@~@ @@  / /_!$)@!@@! $)@@ (_)@!/ /!@ (_)@! / /  \\__,~~~~@ .__/~~~ (_)\n \\$/!|~@$~@$_/! @~!|$_/!\\$/!/_/*\\$/! /_/**!@~** ")!!n
```

This is the magic stored string.

The only real change between the golfed and ungolfed programs is that the golfed program adds some string compression by replacing some common char patterns with `!@$`. The original data string was `667` bytes, after the replace compression it is down to `390` bytes

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 938 Bytes

Revised version with some basic compression of input data: Test [here](https://ideone.com/vB0yyX)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){char e[]="!1`2!3`1!2`1!4`2!4`!1`!4`4!4`1!3`5!4`2!4`2!35^!`!]!1^`!}!}`1!]!1}`2!]!1}!}1!}!2}!`3}!2^!^!2}`3!1}!2^!`!]!2^!`!]!31`!}!}!}!}!1}!}!3*!}!2`1*!}!}!}1!}`!1}!}`1!3^!^`!6^!^!2}!)`*!}!}!)`*!}!2`1!`!`!`1!3`!`1!`!`1!4)`*}!}!}!}!1}!}!2^!^!2}`1!=!1}`1!2`}!}`2!]!1}!(`!]!4^!^!4?!`!=!2]`1-!}!1^!`a!}!(!1]!1}!(`!]!(!1]!4`!}!}`}!}!1}!}!1^!^`!2`2*!}!3}!}!3`2*!}!}!)`*!}!2^!^!4}!)`*!}!3^!^!2]`1-`}`}`}`}!}!/`1^`}`}`}!2)`*!]`2^!2}`}!}`3}!}`3^!4}`}!2}`3^!2]`2^!2^`^!6]`2^!3^`^!16}`}!14",l[]="8578988998>?3",f[666],*q=f,*p=e,c,r;time_t z;time(&z);tm*u=localtime(&z);while(*p){if(*p>47&&*p<58){r=*p++-48;if(*p>47&&*p<58)r=r*10+*p++-48;while(r--)*q++=c;}else{*q++=c=*p++==94?48:p[-1];}}c=u->tm_hour;sprintf(e,"%02d<%02d%c",c%12,u->tm_min,':'+c/12);for(int s,n,o,r=0;r<6;r++){for(q=e;*q;q++){o=r*111;for(n=0; n<*q-48;n++)o+=l[n]-48;s=l[n]-48;for(n=o;n<o+s;n++)putchar(f[n]-1);}putchar('\n');}return 0;}
```

Comment: The headers for this submission don't have all that much influence on the byte size when compared to the data required, so this could actually have a fair chance at winning.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities + [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/), 134

Not sure if figlet is allowed or not, but it does seem to provide the right fonts - `big` for the digits and `small` for the `:` and `{a,p}m`:

```bash
f=figlet\ -f
b()(date +%$1|sed 's/./& /g'|$f big)
b -I|paste - <(echo "    ";$f small ": ") <(b M) <(echo;date +%P|$f small)|tr \\t \
```

The rest is just getting the right info from `date` and shuffling the formating around so it looks right:

```
  ___          _____    ___    
 / _ \    _   | ____|  / _ \               
| (_) |  (_)  | |__   | | | |   __ _ _ __  
 > _ <    _   |___ \  | | | |  / _` | '  \ 
| (_) |  (_)   ___) | | |_| |  \__,_|_|_|_|
 \___/        |____/   \___/
```

Figlet may be installed on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install figlet`.

Comment: oooh didn't think of this loophole. I'll edit the question to make sure that the character data is included in the program, but keep your submission and label it inactive - it's still a good one.

Comment: I did however use figlet to get the data for the numbers, so +1 for figuring that out :)

Comment: Just to make it clear: fonts cannot be loaded from external sources or from libraries.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>994</s> 985 bytes

Terrible attempt with raw data not compressed at all, and a very tacky method for outputting.

But hey... it's only my second codegolf answer!

```js
d="   ___   !  / _ \\  ! | | | | ! | | | | ! | |_| | !  \\___/  0  __  ! /_ | !  | | !  | | !  | | !  |_| 0  ___   ! |__ \\  !    ) | !   / /  !  / /_  ! |____| 0  ____   ! |___ \\  !   __) | !  |__ <  !  ___) | ! |____/  0  _  _    ! | || |   ! | || |_  ! |__   _| !    | |   !    |_|   0  _____  ! | ____| ! | |__   ! |___ \\  !  ___) | ! |____/  0    __   !   / /   !  / /_   ! |  _ \\  ! | (_) | !  \\___/  0  ______  ! |____  | !     / /  !    / /   !   / /    !  /_/     0   ___   !  / _ \\  ! | (_) | !  > _ <  ! | (_) | !  \\___/  0   ___   !  / _ \\  ! | (_) | !  \\__, | !    / /  !   /_/   0   ! _ !(_)! _ !(_)!   0!! __ _ _ __ !/ _` | '  \\!\\__,_|_|_|_|!0!! _ __ _ __ !| '_ \\ '  \\!| .__/_|_|_|!|_|".split(0);
f=a=>{t="toString",s="split",h=a[0][t]()[s](""),m=a[1][s](""),p=a[2]=='am'?11:12,g=h.length>1?1:0,r="";for(i=0;i<6;i++){r+=d[h[0]][s]('!')[i];r+=(g&&1)?d[h[1]][s]('!')[i]:"";r+=d[10][s]('!')[i]+d[m[0]][s]('!')[i]+d[m[1]][s]('!')[i]+d[p][s]('!')[i]+"\n"}return r}
```

**Old submission (994 bytes)**:

```js
d=["   ___   !  / _ \\  ! | | | | ! | | | | ! | |_| | !  \\___/  ","  __  ! /_ | !  | | !  | | !  | | !  |_| ","  ___   ! |__ \\  !    ) | !   / /  !  / /_  ! |____| ","  ____   ! |___ \\  !   __) | !  |__ <  !  ___) | ! |____/  ","  _  _    ! | || |   ! | || |_  ! |__   _| !    | |   !    |_|   ","  _____  ! | ____| ! | |__   ! |___ \\  !  ___) | ! |____/  ","    __   !   / /   !  / /_   ! |  _ \\  ! | (_) | !  \\___/  ","  ______  ! |____  | !     / /  !    / /   !   / /    !  /_/     ","   ___   !  / _ \\  ! | (_) | !  > _ <  ! | (_) | !  \\___/  ","   ___   !  / _ \\  ! | (_) | !  \\__, | !    / /  !   /_/   ","   ! _ !(_)! _ !(_)!   ","!! __ _ _ __ !/ _` | '  \\!\\__,_|_|_|_|!","!! _ __ _ __ !| '_ \\ '  \\!| .__/_|_|_|!|_|"];
f=a=>{
    t="toString",s="split",h=a[0][t]()[s](""),m=a[1][s],p=(a[2]=='am')?11:12,g=(h.length>1)?1:0,r="";
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        r+=d[h[0]].s('!')[i];
        r+=g&&1?d[h[1]].s('!')[i]:"";
        r+=d[10].s('!')[i]+d[m[0]].s('!')[i]+d[m[1]].s('!')[i]+d[p].s('!')[i]+"\n"
    }
return r
}
```

Split into lines to make it easier to read.

Basically:

```js
var f = function (a) {
  hours = a[0].toString().split(""), // convert hours to a string then array to
                                    // handle single and and double numbers
  minutes = a[1].split(""), // ditto with minutes
  period = a[2] == "am" ? 11 : 12, // if it is am, get data[11], if pm, get data[12]
  g = hours.length > 1 ? 1 : 0, // if hours > 9, then g is true
  r = ""; // the string that will be returned
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    r += data[hours[0]].split("!")[i]; // add the first digit of hours to r
    r += g && 1 ? data[hours[1]].split("!")[i] : ""; // if g is true, add the second 
                                                    //digit of hours to r
    r += data[10].split("!")[i] + // colon
    data[minutes[0]].split("!")[i] + // first digit of minutes
    data[minutes[1]].split("!")[i] + // second digit of minutes
    data[period].split("!")[i] + // am/pm
    "\n"; // and finally linebreak.
  } // entire loop repeated six times, each iteration adds one line to the string
return r; // return the string
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, <s>1085</s> 1072 bytes

#### Golfed

```
def f(h,c="",n=["   ___   @  / _ \  @ | | | | @ | | | | @ | |_| | @  \___/  ","  __  @ /_ | @  | | @  | | @  | | @  |_| ","  ___   @ |__ \  @    ) | @   / /  @  / /_  @ |____| ","  ____   @ |___ \  @   __) | @  |__ <  @  ___) | @ |____/  ","  _  _    @ | || |   @ | || |_  @ |__   _| @    | |   @    |_|   ","  _____  @ | ____| @ | |__   @ |___ \  @  ___) | @ |____/  ","    __   @   / /   @  / /_   @ |  _ \  @ | (_) | @  \___/  ","  ______  @ |____  | @     / /  @    / /   @   / /    @  /_/     ","   ___   @  / _ \  @ | (_) | @  > _ <  @ | (_) | @  \___/  ","   ___   @  / _ \  @ | (_) | @  \__, | @    / /  @   /_/   ","   @ _ @(_)@ _ @(_)@   ","            @            @ __ _ _ __ @/ _` | '  \@\__,_|_|_|_|@            ","            @            @ _ __ _ __ @| '_ \ '  \@| .__/_|_|_|@|_|"]):
 for i in range(6):
  for j in range(3):
   if j<2:
    x=int(h[j]);d=x//10;u=x%10
    if d>0 or j>0:c+=n[d].split("@")[i]
    c+=n[u].split("@")[i]
    if j==0:c+=" "+n[10].split("@")[i]+" "
   else:y=11 if h[j]=="am" else 12;c+=" "+n[y].split("@")[i]
  c+="\n"
 return c
```

#### Ungolfed

```
import os
from time import ctime

def asciiClock(hour):
    num = ["   ___   @  / _ \  @ | | | | @ | | | | @ | |_| | @  \___/  @","  __  @ /_ | @  | | @  | | @  | | @  |_| @",
   "  ___   @ |__ \  @    ) | @   / /  @  / /_  @ |____| @","  ____   @ |___ \  @   __) | @  |__ <  @  ___) | @ |____/  @",
   "  _  _    @ | || |   @ | || |_  @ |__   _| @    | |   @    |_|   @","  _____  @ | ____| @ | |__   @ |___ \  @  ___) | @ |____/  @",
   "    __   @   / /   @  / /_   @ |  _ \  @ | (_) | @  \___/  @","  ______  @ |____  | @     / /  @    / /   @   / /    @  /_/     @",
   "   ___   @  / _ \  @ | (_) | @  > _ <  @ | (_) | @  \___/  @","   ___   @  / _ \  @ | (_) | @  \__, | @    / /  @   /_/   @",
   "   @ _ @(_)@ _ @(_)@   @","            @            @ __ _ _ __ @/ _` | '  \@\__,_|_|_|_|@            @",
   "            @            @ _ __ _ __ @| '_ \ '  \@| .__/_|_|_|@|_|@"]
    clock = ""
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(3):
            if j < 2:
                x = int(hour[j])
                d = x // 10
                u = x % 10
                if d > 0 or j > 0:
                    clock += num[d].split("@")[i]
                clock += num[u].split("@")[i]
                if j == 0:
                    clock += " " + num[10].split("@")[i] + " "
            else:
                y = 11 if hour[j] == "am" else 12
                clock += " " + num[y].split("@")[i]
        clock += "\n"
    return clock

previousMinute = -1
while True:
    hour = ctime().split()[3].split(":")
    h = int(hour[0])
    m = hour[1]
    x = "am" if h < 12 else "pm"
    if h > 12:
        h -= 12
    if  previousMinute != m:
        os.system("clear") # if using Windows change to "cls"
        print(asciiClock([h, m, x]))
    previousMinute = m
```